# Is bool a native C type?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, boolean

I've noticed that the Linux kernel code uses bool, but I thought that bool was a C++ type. Is bool a standard C extension (e.g., ISO C90) or a GCC extension?

Comment: Section 9 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) discusses this.

Comment: Direct link: http://www.c-faq.com/bool/index.html

Comment: The Linux kernel uses `-std=gnu89` which supports `_Bool` as an extension to C90. "include/linux/types.h" has `typedef _Bool bool;`.

Comment: Also, FWIW, the Linux kernel 2.6.19 was the first version to use `typedef _Bool bool;` (commit [6e21828743247270d09a86756a0c11702500dbfb](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6e21828743247270d09a86756a0c11702500dbfb)) and it required GNU C 3.2 or later.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

`bool` exists in the current C - C99, but not in C89/90.

In C99 the native type is actually called `_Bool`, while `bool` is a standard library macro defined in `stdbool.h` (which expectedly resolves to `_Bool`). Objects of type `_Bool` hold either 0 or 1, while `true` and `false` are also macros from `stdbool.h`.

Note, BTW, that this implies that C preprocessor will interpret `#if true` as `#if 0` unless `stdbool.h` is included. Meanwhile, C++ preprocessor is required to natively recognize `true` as a language literal.

Comment: There's a new ISO C standard, published in 2011 (after this answer was posted). ANSI, as usual, has adopted the ISO C11 standard as an ANSI standard. For historical reasons, the phrase "ANSI C" commonly (but incorrecetly) refers to the language defined by the ANSI C89 / ISO C90 standard. Since C standards are now published by ISO first, and since there have been three ISO C standards, with varying levels of adoption, it's best to refer to the year the standard was publlshed (ISO C90, ISO C99, ISO C11) to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Does this mean `_Bool` takes up 1 bit of memory?

Comment: @Geremia: No. Why? In C each addressable object has to occupy at least 1 byte. And in real life implementations `_Bool` usually takes 1 byte of memory. However, language specification explicitly permits using `_Bool` as bit-field type, meaning that by using bit-fields you can squeeze a `_Bool` value into a single bit (inside a larger struct).

Comment: @AnT How could a `_Bool` value be both directly addressable (i.e. sized 1 byte) and also participate in a bit-field? An array of `_Bool` would still require all of its elements to be addressable (e.g. `_Bool* ptr = &boolArray[123]`).

Comment: @Dai Your remarks deserve to be a completely separate SO question.

Comment: In C89 for example, how did conditionals and comparative operators work without a native bool type? If I write `if (5 < 6)`, is it all converted to ints under the hood?

Comment: @EkanshdeepGupta Operator < returns an int - zero for false, and non-zero for true (I _think_ it is required to return 1, but I can't be bothered to look it up).  The expression is in an `if` is evaluated, and then the controlled statement is executed if the expression value is non-zero (or non-NULL if the expression is of a pointer type).

Comment: That changes with C23 https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bool_constant

Answer (score 133):

C99 added a builtin `_Bool` data type (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C99) for details), and if you `#include <stdbool.h>`, it provides `bool` as a macro to `_Bool`.

You asked about the Linux kernel in particular.  It assumes the presence of `_Bool` and provides a `bool` typedef itself in [include/linux/types.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.31/include/linux/types.h#L34).

Comment: As to why, it is to allow it ot be undefined and redefined where its definition might cause a clash with legacy code.

Answer (score 36):

C99 has it in [stdbool.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/stdbool.h.html), but in C90 it must be defined as a typedef or enum:

```
typedef int bool;
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

bool f = FALSE;
if (f) { ... }
```

Alternatively:

```
typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } boolean;

boolean b = FALSE;
if (b) { ... }
```

Comment: Note that the behavior of the typedef will be different from that of the C99 `bool`, and also different from that of many compilers' `bit` types.  For example, `bool x=4294967296LL;` or `bool x=0.1;` would set `x` to one on C99, but would likely set most typedef versions to zero.

Answer (score 32):

No, there is no `bool` in ISO C90.

Here's a list of keywords in standard C (not C99):

- `auto`
- `break`
- `case`
- `char`
- `const`
- `continue`
- `default`
- `do`
- `double`
- `else`
- `enum`
- `extern`
- `float`
- `for`
- `goto`
- `if`
- `int`
- `long`
- `register`
- `return`
- `short`
- `signed`
- `static`
- `struct`
- `switch`
- `typedef`
- `union`
- `unsigned`
- `void`
- `volatile`
- `while`

Here's an article discussing some *other* differences with C as used in the kernel and the standard: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gcc-hacks/index.html

Comment: For practical purposes, does it really matter so long as there is still no decent compiler support? Even gcc didn't have half of C99 features until recently, and MSVC doesn't have most of them, and probably never will...

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, the questioner specifically asked about ISO C90. :) In fact, usually when people refer to ANSI C they meaqn C90. I don't use or really plan to use C99 and I think many feel the same way.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe: The original poster explicitly said in a comment that C90 was an example.

Answer (score 28):

```
/* Many years ago, when the earth was still cooling, we used this: */

typedef enum
{
    false = ( 1 == 0 ),
    true = ( ! false )
} bool;

/* It has always worked for me. */
```

Comment: The initial values are entirely unnecessary. `typedef enum { false, true };` is just as good. If you insist on being more explicit, you can write `typedef enum { false = 0, true = 1 };`. (Or just `#include <stdbool.h>` if your compiler supports it; it's been standard for 14 years.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Initial values may be unnecessary, but this answer chooses them in a very elegant way, not with arbitrary values, but using the languages' own semantics and letting the compiler decide.

Comment: @MestreLion:  The language's own semantics guarantee that `typedef enum { false, true } bool;` works exactly as expected. `1 == 0` and `! false` are not elegant, they're merely obfuscated. There's no decision for the compiler to make; it must obey the semantics defined by the language.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I don't think they're obfuscated, I guess the author's intention was to choose the most "natural" values: `false` is set to whatever value the language says an inequality should be evaluated to, and `true` to its "opposite" (again, whatever that is). This way one should not care if that is {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, etc, and it is guaranteed to work in comparisons, because it was *crafted*  using one.

Comment: @MestreLion: Anyone who knows C knows the numeric values of `false` and `true`. Anyone who doesn't know C is not the expected audience for C code. And as I said, C has had a built-in Boolean type since the previous millennium.

Comment: @KeithThompson: you're right on both statements. `#include <stdbool.h>` is the best solution for the past decade :) I was just fond of this quite "language agnostic" trick for choosing the values.

Answer (score 12):

**`_Bool`** is a keyword in C99: it specifies a type, just like `int` or `double`.

> 6.5.2
>
> 2   An object declared as type _Bool
>   is large enough to store the values 0
>   and 1.

Answer (score 9):

C99 defines bool, `true` and `false` in `stdbool.h`.

Answer (score 5):

`stdbool.h` defines macros `true` and `false`, but remember they are defined to be 1 and 0.

That is why `sizeof(true)` equals `sizeof(int)`, which is 4 for 32 bit architectures.

Answer (score 2):

[stdbool.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h) was introduced in c99

Answer (score 2):

C99 added a `bool` type whose semantics are fundamentally different from those of just about all integer types that had existed before in C, including user-defined and compiler-extension types intended for such purposes, and which some programs may have "type-def"ed to `bool`.

For example, given `bool a = 0.1, b=2, c=255, d=256;`, the C99 `bool` type would set all four objects to 1.  If a C89 program used `typedef unsigned char bool`, the objects would receive 0, 2, 255, and 0, respectively.  If it used `char`, the values might be as above, or `c` might be -1.  If it had used a compiler-extension `bit` or `__bit` type, the results would likely be 0, 0, 1, 0 (treating `bit` in a way equivalent to an unsigned bit-field of size 1, or an unsigned integer type with one value bit).

Comment: I don't understand how b=2, in the C89 program using "typedef unsigned char bool", would set the object to 1?  I would have expected 2...  since unsigned char ch = 2; would set ch to 2...

Answer (score 2):

Since C23, `bool`, `true` and `false` are C keywords and don't require any `#include`s.

`bool` becomes one of the fundamental builtin data types.

`_Bool` remains valid and is treated as "Alternative Spelling".

The header `<stdbool.h>` provides only the obsolescent macro `__bool_true_false_are_defined` which expands to the integer constant `1`.

You can find the latest draft here:
https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2912.pdf

Answer (score -1):

No such thing, probably just a macro for int

Comment: Nice with -1's ... the question was C90, not 99 i believe

Comment: well he says C standard *eg* C90, i assume that includes C99.

Comment: He mentiones C90 spesifically, NOT C99, so I assume that what he means. According to wikipedia the only compiler that fully supports C99 is Sun Studio from Sun Microsystems. Now, that's hardly a wide accepted standard is it ? Arguably most modern compilers DO implement parts of the C99 standard, I should probably have mentioned that to avoid stupid comments like yours! What's java or c# to do with this btw?

Comment: *standard C extension (e.g., ISO C90)* is classifying the kind of C standards he's interested in, not specifically C90 itself. an appropriate answer to this is, **yes** a C standard such as C90, specifically the C99 standard, **does** implement a `bool` type.