# Using Boolean values in C

Tags: c, boolean

C doesn't have any built-in Boolean types. What's the best way to use them in C?

Comment: C does have boolean type. At least there is one in the most recent standards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type/1608350#1608350

Answer (score 1266, accepted):

From best to worse:

**Option 1 (C99 and newer)**

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

**Option 2**

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
```

**Option 3**

```
typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };
```

**Option 4**

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

## Explanation

- Option 1 will work only if you use C99 (or newer) and it's the "standard way" to do it. Choose this if possible.
- Options 2, 3 and 4 will have in practice the same identical behavior. #2 and #3 don't use #defines though, which in my opinion is better.

If you are undecided, go with #1!

Comment: Can you elaborate on *why* they are the best to worst choices?

Comment: @endolith The alignment, optimizations and way to store a `<stdbool.h>` `bool` the compiler chooses may be more suitable for the intended purpose of a boolean value than utilizing an `int` (i.e. the compiler may choose to implement a `bool` differently than an `int`). It might also result in stricter type checking at compile time, if you're lucky.

Comment: Why use `int` for `bool`? That's wasteful. Use `unsigned char`. Or use C's builtin `_Bool`.

Comment: @NoBody Using a smaller type can save on memory, but it might not make it any faster. Often, it's faster to use the processor's native word size instead of a smaller size as it could require the compiler to make bit shifts to align it properly

Comment: Options 2-4 do not behave the same as `<stdbool.h>`. For example, they don't satisfy `(bool)(13 & 8) == true`. With options 2-4, you'd have to write `!!(13 & 8) == true` instead. This comes up all the time in bit-field testing... think of a macro that returns `(13 & 8)` with return type `bool`.

Comment: Isn't the easiest way to use 0 for false and >= 1 for true?

Comment: Also, `_Bool x = 0.5; printf("%d", x);` will output `1` while `int x = 0.5; printf("%d", x);` will output 0 instead.

Answer (score 286):

A few thoughts on booleans in C:

I'm old enough that I just use plain `int`s as my boolean type without any typedefs or special defines or enums for true/false values.  If you follow my suggestion below on never comparing against boolean constants, then you only need to use 0/1 to initialize the flags anyway.  However, such an approach may be deemed too reactionary in these modern times.  In that case, one should definitely use `<stdbool.h>` since it at least has the benefit of being standardized.

Whatever the boolean constants are called, use them only for initialization.  Never ever write something like

```
if (ready == TRUE) ...
while (empty == FALSE) ...
```

These can always be replaced by the clearer

```
if (ready) ...
while (!empty) ...
```

Note that these can actually reasonably and understandably be read out loud.

Give your boolean variables positive names, ie `full` instead of `notfull`.  The latter leads to code that is difficult to read easily.  Compare

```
if (full) ...
if (!full) ...
```

with

```
if (!notfull) ...
if (notfull) ...
```

Both of the former pair read naturally, while `!notfull` is awkward to read even as it is, and becomes much worse in more complex boolean expressions.

Boolean arguments should generally be avoided.  Consider a function defined like this

```
void foo(bool option) { ... }
```

Within the body of the function, it is very clear what the argument means since it has a convenient, and hopefully meaningful, name.  But, the call sites look like

```
foo(TRUE);
foo(FALSE):
```

Here, it's essentially impossible to tell what the parameter meant without always looking at the function definition or declaration, and it gets much worse as soon if you add even more boolean parameters.  I suggest either

```
typedef enum { OPT_ON, OPT_OFF } foo_option;
void foo(foo_option option);
```

or

```
#define OPT_ON true
#define OPT_OFF false
void foo(bool option) { ... }
```

In either case, the call site now looks like

```
foo(OPT_ON);
foo(OPT_OFF);
```

which the reader has at least a chance of understanding without dredging up the definition of `foo`.

Comment: And how do you compare two variables for equality? Never using boolean constants works great, but it doesn't solve the problem when comparing against a non-constant.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand the question.  Are you asking how I compare two boolean variables for equality?  If so, doesn't `a == b` work?

Comment: It doesn't work because 'a' might have a value of 3, which is true, and 'b' might have a value of 5, which is true. But a == b should be true as well, which it isn't if they're ints.

Comment: @Kenji What you say is true, although I believe that using values other than one as equivalent for true is almost always a bad idea. So in your example, assuming that  `a` and `b` count up from zero, I'd recommend `a > 0 == b > 0` instead. If you insist on taking advantage of the truthiness of arbitrary non-zero values, `!!var` yields the boolean 0/1 value equivalent to `var`, so you could write `!!a == !!b`, although quite a few readers will find it confusing.

Comment: `!a == !b` is also sufficient for testing equality, non-zeros become zero, and zeros become one.

Comment: @rpattiso You're quite right, of course, but I guess I would read `!!a` as "convert non-boolean a to its equivalent truth value", whereas I'd read `!a` as "logically invert the boolean variable a". In particular, I'd look for some specific reason the logical inversion was desired.

Comment: I would prefer writing some function `bool_equivalent(bool a, bool b)` wherever a comparison of boolean values must be done, since then the intent is clear. Of course, such a function could/should be implemented as `!a == !b` or `!!a == !!b`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: "Note that these can actually reasonably and understandably be read out loud." This might be the most useful advice in any StackOverflow answer I've read to date. Readability of code is a serious problem in general.

Comment: @SebastianGaweda Thanks, I agree with you completely, and that belief goes well beyond boolean variables. Literal, out loud readability of code is an absolutely key indicator. I sometimes call it the "telephone test".

Answer (score 89):

A boolean in C is an integer: zero for false and non-zero for true.

See also [*Boolean data type*, section *C, C++, Objective-C, AWK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Objective-C.2C_AWK).

Comment: It works well with logical operators too (&& and ||).

Answer (score 83):

Here is the version that I used:

```
typedef enum { false = 0, true = !false } bool;
```

Because false only has one value, but a logical true could have many values, but technique sets true to be what the compiler will use for the opposite of false.

This takes care of the problem of someone coding something that would come down to this:

```
if (true == !false)
```

I think we would all agree that that is not a good practice, but for the one time cost of doing "true = !false" we eliminate that problem.

[EDIT] In the end I used:

```
typedef enum { myfalse = 0, mytrue = !myfalse } mybool;
```

to avoid name collision with other schemes that were defining `true` and `false`.  But the concept remains the same.

[EDIT] To show conversion of integer to boolean:

```
mybool somebool;
int someint = 5;
somebool = !!someint;
```

The first (right most) ! converts the non-zero integer to a 0, then the second (left most) ! converts the 0 to a `myfalse` value.  I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to convert a zero integer.

[EDIT]
It is my style to use the explicit setting of a value in an enum when the specific value is required even if the default value would be the same.  Example: Because false needs to be zero I use `false = 0,` rather than `false,`

[EDIT]
Show how to limit the size of enum when compiling with gcc:

```
typedef __attribute__((__packed__)) enum { myfalse = 0, mytrue = !myfalse } mybool;
```

That is, if someone does:

```
struct mystruct {
    mybool somebool1;
    mybool somebool2;
    mybool somebool3;
    mybool somebool4;
}
```

the size of the structure will be 4 bytes rather than 16 bytes.

Comment: Also another benefit to using enums is the IDE integration - `true`, `false` and `bool` are highlighted in most IDE's because they are enum values and a typedef, as opposed to `#defines`, which are rarely ever syntax highlighted.

Comment: Curious: Ignoring whether or not it actually works, is it valid C(99+) to allow an enum to reference a prior value in the *same enumeration*?

Comment: @tgm1024 `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall` gives no warnings, so I trust `gcc`; If this works even for `c89` it should work for `c99` aswell.

Comment: *"Because false only has one value, but a logical true could have many values, but technique sets true to be what the compiler will use for the opposite of false."* Negation operator `!` can only return values `0` and `1`, so `true = !false` will always assign value 1. This method does not give any extra safety over `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`.

Comment: @user694733 Do you have a reference from the standard that !0 always returns 1?  And if so, have all C compilers implemented to the standard?

Comment: Earliest I found is from C90 (6.3.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators): *"The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0. 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is equivalent to (O==E)."* That should cover any compiler that has ever claimed to support standard C. Compilers can of course be legally ignore this rule in cases where it doesn't matter for the observable behaviour (like `if(!value)`), but that exception is not applicable in this specific case.

Comment: Those custom ones are 4 bytes long, it's impractical to use them. Is there any way we can implement that with type of CHAR?

Comment: @DickWilliams Good point about being 4 bytes.  I am going to give that some thought on how to use a typedef unsigned char bool and only use const unsigned char b_false = 0; const unsigned char b_true = !b_false;

Comment: @DickWilliams Apparently you can "Pack" an enum in gcc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879286/specifying-size-of-enum-type-in-c

Comment: @BeKindToNewUsers Yeah. Thanks. I've used it like this : `typedef unsigned char bool`, `#define true 1`, `#define false 0`. And that's it.

Answer (score 53):

If you are using a C99 compiler it has built-in support for bool types:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
  bool b = false;
  b = true;
}
```

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Objective-C.2C_AWK)

Comment: @JamesStevens that is not right. There is a buit-in type called `_Bool`. It's not an enum. `bool`, `true` and `false` are macros defined in `<stdbool.h>` that expand to `_Bool`, `1` and `0` respectively.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean

Answer (score 49):

First things first. C, i.e. ISO/IEC 9899 has had a boolean type for **19 years now**. That is way longer time than the [expected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) length of the C programming career with amateur/academic/professional parts combined when visiting **this question**. Mine does surpass that by mere perhaps 1-2 years. It means that during the time **that an average reader has learnt anything at all about C, C actually has had the boolean data type**.

For the datatype, `#include <stdbool.h>`, and use `true`, `false` and `bool`. Or do not include it, and use `_Bool`, `1` and `0` instead.

---

There are various **dangerous** practices promoted in the other answers to this thread. I will address them:

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

This is no-no, because a casual reader - who did learn C within those 19 years - would expect that `bool` refers to the **actual** `bool` data type and would behave similarly, but it doesn't! For example

```
double a = ...;
bool b = a;
```

With C99 `bool`/ `_Bool`, `b` would be set to `false` **iff** `a` was zero, and `true` otherwise. [C11 6.3.1.2p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.1)

> 1. When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1. 59)
>
> **Footnotes**
>
> 59) NaNs do not compare equal to 0 and thus convert to 1.

With the `typedef` in place, the `double` would be coerced to an `int` - if the value of the double isn't in the range for `int`, the **behaviour is undefined**.

Naturally the same applies to if `true` and `false` were declared in an `enum`.

What is even **more dangerous** is declaring

```
typedef enum bool {
    false, true
} bool;
```

because now **all values** besides 1 and 0 are invalid, and should such a value be assigned to a variable of that type, **the behaviour would be wholly undefined**.

Therefore **iff** you cannot use C99 for some inexplicable reason, for boolean variables you should use:

- type `int` and values `0` and `1` **as-is**; and carefully do domain conversions from any other values to these with double negation `!!`
- or if you **insist** you don't remember that 0 is falsy and non-zero truish, at least use **upper case** so that they don't get confused with the C99 concepts: `BOOL`, `TRUE` and `FALSE`!

Comment: What part of the C Standard would limit objects of enumerated types to holding the values explicitly listed therein?  If the largest value for an enumerated constant is less than UCHAR_MAX or USHRT_MAX, an implementation could use a type smaller than `int` or `unsigned int` to hold an enumeration, but I know of nothing in the Standard that would cause an enumeration to behave as anything other than an integer type.

Answer (score 17):

```
typedef enum {
    false = 0,
    true
} t_bool;
```

Comment: @Andrew That's not true. `!0 = 1` by the C standard, and `!a = 0` for any non-zero value of `a`. The problem is that any non-zero is considered as true. So if `a` and `b` are both "true", it isn't necessarily the case that ` a == b`.

Answer (score 14):

C has a boolean type: **bool** (at least for the last 10(!) years)

Include stdbool.h and true/false will work as expected.

Comment: 10 years in the standard, but not 10 years in compilers! MSVC++'s C compilation does not support C99 at all other than allowing // comments, and is not ever likely to do so.  Also _Bool is defined in C99 as a built-in type, while bool is a typedef in the <stdbool.h> header.

Comment: @Clifford 4 years on since your comment...nothing has changed. MSVC is a C++ compiler and I believe MS have said that they are not really keen on supporting all new C features (C99 & C11). But I can't take that MSVC doesn't support new C features as a reason (especially when you say it against a *10 years on* answer). 10 years is really a long time in the programming world. Any decent compiler should have support for it in much less than 10 years if the vendor is intended to support it.

Comment: @KingsIndian:  I am not sure why you directed your comment to me or even felt the need to comment at all.  I was only stating the situation as it stood at the time of writing. I was not supporting that situation, merely pointing out that the "answer" may not apply in all circumstances.

Comment: @Clifford: Strictly, the standard requires `bool` to be a macro that expands to `_Bool`.  The difference matters because you can `#undef` a macro (and that's permitted, at least as a transitional measure), but you can't `untypedef` a typedef.  It doesn't alter the main thrust of your first comment, though.

Comment: VS2015 and later (& possibly earlier, up to a point) have no problem with `bool` through `<stdbool.h>` under C compilation. It resolves to `_Bool`.

Answer (score 13):

Anything nonzero is evaluated to true in boolean operations, so you could just

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

and use the constants.

Comment: but use them with care: since a true result may be any non-zero value, the tests if(t==TRUE){...} and if(t), which are equivalent in other languages, are not equivalent in C.

Comment: You're right, but that's also true in C++ which does have a bool type, right? During debugging i've seen bool variables with values of 5837834939...

Comment: In C++, the if(t == true) test equals the if(t) test, because C++ does some conversion (everything which is not 0 or a null pointer value is converted to true)

Comment: All you should assume about a boolean true value is that it is non-zero.  So code like if( b ) is safe while if( b == TRUE) is not; the latter is bad practice (and pointless).

Answer (score 8):

This is just a complement to other answers and some clarification, if you are allowed to use [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).

```
+-------+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
|  Name | Characteristic | Dependence in stdbool.h |        Value       |
+-------+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| _Bool |   Native type  |    Don't need header    |                    |
+-------+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
|  bool |      Macro     |           Yes           | Translate to _Bool |
+-------+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
|  true |      Macro     |           Yes           |   Translate to 1   |
+-------+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| false |      Macro     |           Yes           |   Translate to 0   |
+-------+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
```

Some of my preferences:

- `_Bool` or `bool`?  Both are fine, but `bool` looks better than the keyword `_Bool`.
- Accepted values for `bool` and `_Bool` are: `false` or `true`. Assigning `0` or `1` instead of `false` or `true` is valid, but is harder to read and understand the logic flow.

Some information from the standard:

- `_Bool` is *not* `unsigned int`, but is part of the group *unsigned integer types*. It is large enough to hold the values `0` or `1`.
- *Do not*, but yes, you are able to redefine `bool` `true` and `false` but sure is not a good idea. This ability is considered obsolescent and will be removed in future.
- Assigning an *scalar type* (arithmetic types and pointer types) to `_Bool` or `bool`, if the *scalar* value is equal to `0` or compares to `0` it will be `0`, otherwise the result is `1`:  `_Bool x = 9;` `9` is converted to `1` when assigned to `x`.
- `_Bool` is 1 byte (8 bits), usually the programmer is tempted to try to use the other bits, but is not recommended, because the only guaranteed that is given is that only one bit is use to store data, not like type `char` that have 8 bits available.

Comment: As bool is "kind of" an unsigned integer, the use boolean values in numerical expressions like `a_is_used*a + b_is_used*b` seems to be allowed. It looks quite readable.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) supports boolean types but you need to `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Example:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() 
{ 
    bool arr[2] = {true, false}; 

    printf("%d\n", arr[0] && arr[1]);
    printf("%d\n", arr[0] || arr[1]);

    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Comment: This is more or less a repeat of previous answers. What is new (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen  Kalana's answer is an improvement on other answers because it includes a self contained sample code with the output.

Answer (score 3):

#### Since [C23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/23)

[`bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/bool) and [`_Bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/_Bool), and [`true` and `false`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bool_constant) are language keywords for [boolean types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Boolean_type). `bool`/`_Bool` is a type that can hold either the value `true` or `false`. [Logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) `!`, `||`, and `&&` can be used.

A scalar-typed value can be [implicitly converted to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Boolean_conversion). Zero-valued arithmetic types convert to `false`, as well as `null` pointers, or anything of type [`nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/nullptr_t). Any other scalar-type values convert to `true`. Rules for promotion to higher-rank integer types can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

The macros `bool`, `true`, and `false` from `<stdbool.h>` are "removed" (from that header specifically), but an implementation can still define such predefined macros for compatibility, and implementations can still use macros to implement them, and if that is done, programs can still undefine and redefine them. The macro `__bool_true_false_are_defined` is deprecated.

See also https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2935.pdf.

#### Since [C99](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/99)

[`_Bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/_Bool) is a language keyword for a [boolean type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Boolean_type) that can hold either the value `1` or `0`. [Logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) `!`, `||`, and `&&` can be used.

When [converting scalar types to `_Bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Boolean_conversion), any value that compares equal to zero is converted to `0`, and other value is converted to `1`. Rules for promotion to higher-rank integer types can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

The standard header [`<stdbool.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types#:%7E:text=Defined%20in%20header%20%3Cstdbool.h%3E) provides a convenience macro that defines `bool` as an alias to `_Bool`, a macro `true` that expands to the *integer*-type (not `_Bool`!) constant `1`, a macro `false` that expands to the *integer* constant `0`, and a macro `__bool_true_false_are_defined` that expands to the integer constant `1`. Programs are allowed to undefine and redefine the macros `bool`, `true`, and `false`.

#### Prior to C99

You could write something like `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional expressions are considered to be true if they are non-zero, but the C standard requires that logical operators themselves return either 0 or 1.

@Tom: #define TRUE !FALSE is bad and is completely pointless.  If the header file makes its way into compiled C++ code, then it can lead to problems:

```
void foo(bool flag);

...

int flag = TRUE;
foo(flag);
```

Some compilers will generate a warning about the int => bool conversion.  Sometimes people avoid this by doing:

```
foo(flag == TRUE);
```

to force the expression to be a C++ bool.  But if you #define TRUE !FALSE, you end up with:

```
foo(flag == !0);
```

which ends up doing an int-to-bool comparison that can trigger the warning anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could use _Bool, but the return value must be an integer (1 for true, 0 for false).
However, It's recommended to include  and use bool as in C++, as said in
[this reply](https://www.daniweb.com/posts/jump/1057160) from [daniweb forum](https://www.daniweb.com), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767954/9034686), from this other stackoverflow question:

> _Bool: C99's boolean type. Using _Bool directly is only recommended if you're maintaining legacy code that already defines macros for bool, true, or false. Otherwise, those macros are standardized in the  header. Include that header and you can use bool just like you would in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a char, or another small number container for it.

**Pseudo-code**

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

char bValue = TRUE;
```

Comment: Also in C it's usually an int, and it can cause loss of precision warnings by other code that uses int..

Comment: Unless you are hand-optimising for space, it's always better to use the hardware's normal word-size (e.g.: usually an `int`), since on some architectures you get a significant performance hit from having to unpack/mask checks on these variables.

Answer (score 1):

It is this:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

Comment: Id go with something like #define TRUE !FALSE

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C99 then you can use the `_Bool` type. No `#include`s are necessary. You do need to treat it like an integer, though, where `1` is `true` and `0` is `false`.

You can then define `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

```
_Bool this_is_a_Boolean_var = 1;


//or using it with true and false
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
_Bool var = TRUE;
```

Comment: Or you can `#include <stdbool.h>` and use `bool`, `true`, and `false` like the standard wants you to.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
enum {false, true};
typedef _Bool bool;
```

`_Bool` is a built in type in C. It's intended for boolean values.

Comment: Nobody should be doing this. The false and true macros in ``stdbool.h`` are ``_Bool``-typed starting in C23. Using an enum like this subtly breaks comparison operators because you don't get automatic casts to ``_Bool``.

Answer (score -4):

You can simply use the `#define` directive as follows:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define NOT(arg) (arg == TRUE)? FALSE : TRUE
typedef int bool;
```

And use as follows:

```
bool isVisible = FALSE;
bool isWorking = TRUE;
isVisible = NOT(isVisible);
```

and so on

Comment: The NOT macro should be protected by parentheses around the `arg` and the expression as a whole: `#define NOT(arg) (((arg) == TRUE) ? FALSE : TRUE)`.  However, it would be better to test for falseness (it will give the correct answer even if `arg` was 23 instead of 0 or 1: `#define NOT(arg) (((arg) == FALSE) ? TRUE : FALSE)`.  But the whole expression can be reduced to `#define NOT(arg) (!(arg))`, of course, which produces the same result.