# C while loop multiple conditions math

Tags: c

Im very new to `c` and am trying to make a `while` loop that checks if the parameter is less than or equal to a certain number but also if it is greater than or equal to a different number as well. I usually code in `python` and this is example of what I'm looking to do in `c`:

`while(8 <= x <= 600)`

Comment: For a while loop to process the information the condition needs to be true. So if you start at 0 you will not execute the while loop. The syntax you have is valid, all you need is an expression inside the while, If the expression evaluates to 0 it will not evaluate else it will. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254075/using-true-and-false-in-c

Answer (score 3):

```
while (x >= 8 && x <= 600){

}
```

Comment: Then please be at least so kind to accept the answer which worked fine for you, @max fugate.

Answer (score 0):

The relational and equality operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, and `!=`) don't work like that in C.  The expression `a <= b` will evaluate to 1 if the condition is true, 0 otherwise.  The operator is *left-associative*, so `8 <= x <= 600` will be evaluated as `(8 <= x) <= 600`.  `8 <= x` will evaluate to 0 or 1, both of which are less than 600, so the result of the expression is always 1 (true).

To check if `x` falls within a range of values, you have to do two separate comparisons: `8 <= x && x <= 600` (or `8 > x || x > 600`)

Answer (score -1):

this one means if x>=8，if x is bigger than 8 ,it turns 1 <= 600 ；(always true)
if not , Then it turns 0<=600 ; (always fause)

Comment: @user3078414 I don't know what the x value is ?  Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: In that case, please don't give answers before you _know_ what you are answering to. You have comments to ask additional information...