# When does N & (1<<x) == true?

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation

I've recently been studying complete search with generating subsets using bit operations, so I've stumbled upon the following code:

```
for(int b = 0; b < (1<<n); b++) {
    vector<int> subset;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if( b&(1<<i)) subset.push_back(i);
    }
    //use subset here
}
```

This code is used to find all subsets of a set of `n` elements. I'm confused by the part

```
b&(1<<i)
```

Which is clearly false if the i-th bit of `b` is `0`, but I don't see why it'd be  `true` if the i-th bit of `b` is `true`, I mean wouldn't the result just be `2` to the power of `i` (which as it doesn't equal one i.e. true, should return `false`)?

**changes**: 
Beside that, I noticed now that I know that any number different from zero is considered `true`, that `N & (1<<x) == true` is true if `x` is `0` and `N` is odd, or `x>0` and `N` is even, due to the preference of `==` over `&` , so `N & (1<<x) == true` resolves to `N & ( (1<<x) == true )`

Comment: Though I do know I can just put (  b & ( 1<<i )  ) >> i to get the value of the i-th bit of b, it just doesn't seem to me that that part was missed in the book I was studying from.

Comment: Here is a nice [list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions) which types can be implicitly converted to `bool`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In c, in bool, true == 1 and false == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009029/in-c-in-bool-true-1-and-false-0)

Comment: The question in the title is **different from** the question in the code. When you compare a numeric expression with `true`, `true` gets promoted to `int` with the value 1, and the comparison succeeds only if the value of the expression is also 1. When you use a numeric expression in an `if()` statement its value is contextually converted to `bool`, and any non-zero value will be converted to `true`.

Comment: oh, I didn't understand that, mind elaborating?

Comment: Please take discussion to chat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a small misunderstanding...

> which as it doesn't equal one i.e. true, should return false )

The truth is: only `0` is converted to `false` while all other numbers become `true`.

Answer (score 3):

> Which is clearly false if the i-th bit of `b` is `0`, but I don't see why it'd be  `true` if the i-th bit of `b` is `true`, I mean wouldn't the result just be `2` to the power of `i` (which as it doesn't equal one i.e. true, should return `false`)?

Your mistake here is not that `1` is `true` and all others is `false`.  In C++ `0` is `false` and all other values are `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that when a numeric expression is used  in C or C++ in places where a logical expression is needed, such as `if`s or `while`s, the expression result is implicitly compared to zero. Expressions returning zero mean "false", while expressions returning non-zero mean "true". They do not need to return `1`<sup>*</sup>.

Now recall that `1 << i` constructs a number with the binary representation that has a single `1` in i-th position. Performing an `&` of a number `b` with such number yields zero when `b`-th bit at position `i` is zero. When `b`s bit in position `i` is one, the expression produces a non-zero value, which is interpreted as "true" by the `if` statement.

<sup>*</sup> When C or C++ evaluates a logical expression, such as `!` or `&&`, it produces `1`, not an arbitrary non-zero number.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common confusion, you mixed 2 things:

- boolean to integer conversion: `true` is converted to 1, `false` is converted to 0
- integer to boolean conversion: 0 converted to `false`, anything else is converted to `true`.

so when you use expression which result is `int` in `if` or `while` or any other statement that requires boolean value you implicitly convert it to `bool` hence second case. This code:

```
if( b&(1<<i)) subset.push_back(i);
```

is logically the same as:

```
bool flag = b&(1<<i);
if( flag ) subset.push_back(i);
```