# How do a sort this list on two keys

Tags: c#, list, sorting

```
public class Witness
{
    public Mobile m_mobile;
    public bool m_hasLOS;
    public double m_distanceToSqrt;
    public Witness(Mobile m, bool hasLOS, double distanceToSqrt)
    {
        m_mobile = m;
        m_hasLOS = hasLOS;
        m_distanceToSqrt = distanceToSqrt;
    }
}
```

I've created a list of these objects 'witnesses' and now want to sort it on both m_hasLOS and m_distanceToSqrt.

In my code I call:

```
List<Witness> sorted = witnesses.OrderBy(x => x.m_hasLOS).ThenBy(x => x.m_distanceToSqrt).ToList();
```

This works, but the list is not ordered how I would like. How do I change the ordering such that: LOS is always at the top of the list, ordered on ascending distance?
And where LOS is false, the list is then just ascending distance?

For example:

```
o1: m_LOS = true, m_distanceToSqrt = 13
o2: m_LOS = false, m_distanceToSqrt = 6
o3: m_LOS = false, m_distanceToSqrt = 2
```

Should yield the reaultant sort:

```
o1: m_LOS = true, m_distanceToSqrt = 13
o3: m_LOS = false, m_distanceToSqrt = 2
o2: m_LOS = false, m_distanceToSqrt = 6
```

Comment: note, that `false < true`, thats why `.OrderByDescending(x => x.m_hasLOS).ThenBy(x => x.m_distanceToSqrt)`. Please, note *Descending*

Comment: If you don't want to remember whether `false<true` or `false>true`, convert the bool to something you know the sort direction of.. `OrderBy(x => x.HasLOS ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: C# naming conventions for public members is PascalCase, no prefixing

Comment: Thank you, Perfect. Just what I needed. 
@Caius, yea, I was trying to minimize the example size by omitting the PascalCase public properties.

Comment: No problems! It was a Lesson In Love indeed . ba dum tish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C family of languages (and many others), [you can think of `false` as being equal to `0` and `true` being equal to `1` (more specifically anything that is not `0`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009029/in-c-in-bool-true-1-and-false-0).

So sorting on a `boolean` field will return all `false` values first when the sort order is ascending because `0 < 1`. If you want the `true` values first, you will need to use the descending sort order.

For `OrderBy`, that is [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0). For `ThenBy`, that is [`ThenByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending?view=net-6.0). In your case, you just need to use the first.

```cs
List<Witness> sorted = witnesses
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.m_hasLOS)
    .ThenBy(x => x.m_distanceToSqrt)
    .ToList();
```

[Try it out on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VWAMMR).

---

Side note, [public members should use pascal casing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#pascal-case), [properties should be preferred over public fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295109/14956277) in order to abstract implementation details from class responsibilities, and [variable names should favor readability over length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).

The conventional way to write your class definition would be:

```cs
public class Witness
{
    private Mobile mobile;
    private bool hasLineOfSight;
    private double distanceToSquareRoot;

    public Mobile Mobile 
    {
        get => mobile;
        set => mobile = value;
    }

    public bool HasLineOfSight
    {
        get => hasLineOfSight;
        set => hasLineOfSight = value;
    }

    public double DistanceToSquareRoot
    {
        get => distanceToSquareRoot;
        set => distanceToSquareRoot = value;
    }

    public Witness(Mobile mobile, bool hasLineOfSight, double distanceToSquareRoot)
    {
        Mobile = mobile;
        HasLineOfSight = hasLineOfSight;
        DistanceToSquareRoot = distanceToSquareRoot;
    }
}
```

Since you don't have any methods on your class, if its primary use is as a value type, you could use the [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records) type instead.

```cs
public record Witness(
    Mobile Mobile, 
    bool HasLineOfSight, 
    double DistanceToSquareRoot
);
```