# Is it okay to put comments between arguments of a function call in C?

Tags: c

I have to call a function from main function like:

```
void main()
...
...
...
printf("Starting function- saveSubscriber");
  status = saveSubscriber(io_ctr,
                   i_pRec,
                   /*&ufpEsn,*/     **/* Change #6*/**
                   iov_pmktbuf,
                   &i_pCntRec,       **/* Change #23 */**
                   iv_pActvBuf->pr ); 

...
...
}
```

Is putting comments beside arguments (**/* Change #6*/** and **/* Change #23*/**) okay?  That is, will the code compile and will it function the same as when there are no comments.

Comment: Sure.  But this is an opinion question and therefore OT

Comment: Yes it is perfectly fine and the normal way to comment on complex function calls.

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely fine. Compiler skip these comments during Lexical Analysis phase.

Comment: The *contents* of the comments aren't great, though - that's the sort of information that's managed for you by your source-code repository tool.  Good comments convey immediately-useful information to the reader.

Comment: Thank you all. I don't remember but I read somewhere that putting comments like this during function call may create some issue, don't remember what and where I read this, so asked!

Comment: To track changes, use a revision management/repository system like git or svn. Comments like this ill eventually adn very quickly result in chaos.

Answer (score 4):

The comment syntax is fine.

For me commenting arguments is a sign, that the name of the argument is not chosen clearly.

Moreover, commenting out a complete agrument leaves me a bit puzzled. It seams like somebody changed the signature of the function and was too lazy to clean it up properly.

Comment: "commenting arguments is a sign, that the name of the argument is not chosen clearly" The comment may as well tell what that particular parameter of the function _does_, not so much to document what the particular argument _is_.

Comment: Thank you all. I don't remember but I read somewhere that putting comments like this during function call may create some issue, don't remember what and where I read this, so asked!

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine, as others have said.

However, you might be able to avoid this if  you use meaningful variable names.

I also find myself declaring a lot of differently named enums, which are basically just Boolean.

Which is clearer?

1)

```
processData(1);  // you might add acomemnt to explain what 1 means.
                 // Many won't bother (especially those @~£%$!! who write  
                 // code that I have to main years later !!)
```

2)

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
...

processData(TRUE);
```

3)

```
typedef enum {deleteDuplicates, retainDuplicates} howTohandleDuplicates_t;

processData(deleteDuplicates);
```

Always try your best to write maintainable, easy to read, code. Comments are fine, but well chosen variable names can obviate the need for most of them

Comment: Thank you. I don't remember but I read somewhere that putting comments like this during function call may create some issue, don't remember what and where I read this, so asked!

Comment: Hmm, Perhaps a different example than `TRUE`.  see[Using true and false in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2254075/2410359)

Comment: True/Fasle is what I most commonly see "misused" (in my opinion).

Comment: Any reason for the downvote, whoever did it?