# What is the C99 _Bool data type and how do you use it?

Tags: c, types, boolean, c99

What is the C99 `_Bool` data type and how do you use it?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Include [`<stdbool.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h) header

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){
  bool b = false;
}
```

Macros `true` and `false` expand to `1` and `0` respectively.

Section `7.16` **Boolean type and values `< stdbool.h >`**

> - 1      The header `<stdbool.h>` deﬁnes four macros.
> - 2      The macro
>
>   - bool
>       expands to _Bool.
> - 3      The remaining three macros are suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives.  They
>     are
>
>   - true : which expands to the integer constant 1,
>   - false: which expands to the integer constant 0, and
>   - __bool_true_false_are_defined
>       which expands to the integer constant 1.
> - 4      Notwithstanding  the  provisions  of  7.1.3,  a  program  may  undeﬁne  and  perhaps  then
>     redeﬁne the macros bool, true, and false.

Comment: It should also be noted that conversion to `_Bool` (by assignment, cast, etc.) is effectively by prefixing the expression with `!!`.

Answer (score 61):

Please do check out the answer here on this related thread found on [DaniWeb](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread240998.html).

extracted and quoted here for convenient reference:-

---

### usage of new keywords in c99

> **_Bool**: C99's boolean type. Using _Bool directly is only recommended if you're
>   maintaining legacy code that already
>   defines macros for bool, true, or
>   false. Otherwise, those macros are
>   standardized in the `<stdbool.h>`
>   header. Include that header and you
>   can use bool just like you would in
>   C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main ( void )
{
  bool b = true;

  if ( b )
    printf ( "Yes\n" );
  else
    printf ( "No\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: +1 for explanation of why `_Bool` exists along with `bool`. Very helpful to understand it.