# Can you define a function returning bool in C?

Tags: c, loops

I have very little experience in C or C++, so I don't understand some of the various shortcuts and common tasks in the language.

I'm looking at game code that looks similar to this:

```
bool
update_frame (void)
{
  // Various bits of code
  return TRUE;
}
```

This is the main loop of the game. I'm thinking that it's similar to something like:

```
while (true) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Which I would use in C# or Java. Is this what's going on here?

Comment: Can you please be a little clearer as to what exactly your question is?

Comment: You need to be clearer with your question. But to answer the titular question.... Yes, you can define a function returning bool in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is likely using a game engine. The engine will call `update_frame` 30/60/X times per second. In between, however, it might perform other tasks.

It probably functions as a while(true) loop, though.

Answer (score 0):

No tricks in the function you mentioned, its just a simple function.... the loop is probably in some other function that is calling this function.

tip: try locating that calling function for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

bool is just one data type just like int, float....etc

In c you can not give name of function same as any data types or keywords.

In your code i think bool is not part of your function name...it is just return type of that function

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is it what you're asking, I can say that your pieces of code mean absolutely the same in C, Java and C#: the first one is a function returning `bool`, the second one is an infinite loop.

What is the question, again?

Comment: Your answer seems like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple function which returns a bool value. But, as you say it was for a game, I think somewhere in the code(probably main function) it sets this function as an update function, with a command like this:

```
setUpdateFrameFunc(update_frame);
```

And after this line, it will make a thread and run this function on that thread over and over. Finally, It seems that the code on the function is running in a while(true) loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think (at least the title implies) that you wonder how it is possible to specify `true` and `bool` in C, yes?

ANSI C (C89/C90) does not provide a special data type for booleans; boolean functionality is expressed using integers, where 0 stands for "false" and everything else is interpreted as "true".

C99 provides "built-in support", though, by defining appropriate macros as you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type).

So, either the code you are looking at is using C99 (check whether the  header is included somewhere) or `bool` is a typedef macro, so look out whether there's a

```
typedef int bool;
```

or something similar to be found in the code. The mere fact that it says "return TRUE" would imply the latter, since `TRUE` is very common in ANSI C and most often defined as

```
#define TRUE 1
```

So again you may look out for that.

As to your other question what that function might do, it could be implemented similar to a "game loop"/while(true) loop, like this:

```
while (update_frame()) { /* render current state to screen */
  /* do game logic */
}
```