# What is best approach to define function which takes true or false as parameter in C

Tags: c

As title stated, I'm writing function taking 2 boolean as parameters but don't know what is the best way to do! What are your suggestions?

Comment: Use integers and interpret them to be true iff they are different from zero, false otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two `int` values should work fine:

```
void func(int x, int y)
{
   if(x) // x is non-zero
   {
      // do something
   }
   if(y) // z is non-zero
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

```
func(0, 1); // x is false, y is true
```

You could `#define` `true` and `false` to be something like `1` and `0`:

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
```

```
func(FALSE, TRUE);
```

Comment: Or, for C99, `#include <stdbool.h>` and use the `bool` type.

Comment: this way looks really ugly ^^

Comment: Why not use stdbool.h? C99 is 12 years old.

Comment: is C99 supported for all companies?

Comment: Somewhere, some company is still using pre C89 code. If your compiler doesn't support C99 you should stop using it. As I said, it's been twelve years, they've had enough time implementing it.

Comment: @JonnyKeogh, still there exist compilers (eg. MSVC) which are not C99 compliant.

Comment: No please, don't redefine true and false, use TRUE and FALSE please!

Answer (score 2):

c99 already provides the `bool` data type if you are using that, you can use it directly.

Else another ways are:

**Simple way**: Use integers and treat 0 as false and 1 as true.

**Verbose way**: Create enum with true and false names and use that.

**Code Sample:**

```
typedef enum 
{
    FALSE = 0,
    TRUE = 1
}Boolean;

int doSomething(Boolean var1, Boolean var2)
{
   if(var1 == TRUE)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Boolean var1 = FALSE;
    Boolean var2 = TRUE;

    int ret = doSomething(var1,var2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the C99 bool type

```
#include <stdbool.h> //don't forget to include this library

void func(bool a, bool b)
{


}

int main(void)
{
     bool a = true, b = false;
     func(a, b);
     return 0;
}
```

take a look at :
[C99 boolean data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum boolean_t{
    FALSE = 0,
    TRUE
}boolean;

int main(){
    fun1(TRUE);
}

int fun1(boolean val)
{
    if (val == TRUE){
        printf("True\n");
    }else{
        printf("False\n");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.   An int can act like a bool.  Zero is false. Everything else is true.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function (int boolValue)
{
    if (boolValue)
    {
        printf("true");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("false");
    }
} 

int main(void)
{
    function(1 == 2);
    function(1 > 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If size matters to you, you could as well try (assuming you only have a C89 Compiler)

```
#define false 0
#define true  1
typedef char Boolean;

//...
Boolean test = true;
if( test )
    puts("Heya!");
else
    puts("Not Heya!");
//...
```

and your `Boolean` is guaranteed to have `sizeof() == 1`