# Usage of #ifdef in between if else condition

Tags: c, cross-platform, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

```
   #ifndef _WINDOWS
   if(condition)
   {
     printf("to do in linux"); 
   }
   else
   #endif
   {
      printf("should work in both linux and windows...");
   }
```

My question: does this code work for both in linux and windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `#ifdef`, `#ifndef` and `#endif` are preprocessor's directives, these will be applied before the compilation starts, ignoring the following lines completely in case `_WINDOWS` is defined:

```
#ifndef _WINDOWS
if(condition)
{
  printf("to do in linux"); 
}
else
#endif
```

Note that the `condition` will be evaluated only in case it is not on Windows.

On Windows, there will be nothing but the following nested anonymous scope:

```
{
   printf("should work in both linux and windows...");
}
```

Comment: thanks.. and in the case of linux it will be                                if(true) { printf("to do in linux") } else { printf("should work in both linux..."); }    is this right?

Comment: @zeal: You should use only the latter one. In case of Linux, both `printf` statements will be executed.

Comment: sorry the question would be if(condition) mistakely i had written if(true)

Comment: #ifndef _WINDOWS
  if(condition) printf("to do in linux"); else 
#endif
{printf("should work in both linux and windows...");}

Comment: @zeal: See my edit. Should `condition` be evaluated in both Linux and Windows?

Comment: @zeal: In that case your logic was correct all the time. See my last edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38713/discussion-between-zeal-and-liho)

Answer (score 4):

You have more logic than you need - you can just do this:

```
#ifndef _WINDOWS
     printf("to do in Linux"); 
     // ...
#endif
     printf("to do in both Linux and Windows");
     // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the ELSE statement won't run on Linux, because the compiled source code would be:

```
if(true)
{
   printf("to do in linux");
}
else
{
   printf("should work in both linux and windows and i have multiple statements in this else bolck");
}
```

And keep in mind that instead of `true` in C we have non-zero values, so `if(1)` for example (or you need a proper define for `true` keyword, or just `#include  like @JonathanLeffler suggests).

But you could have definitely tried it with different defines in your code.

Comment: Where have you been hiding these last 14 years or so? C99 introduced `<stdbool.h>` which defines `bool`, `true` and `false`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, but what can we find there? `#define true 1 \n #define false 0`. `true` and `false` are NOT keywords, just defines. All is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4767943/882200 So my point is 100% valid and since the question was quite simple, the answer has to be precise. Or we could use jQuery for that and learn nothing ;]

Answer (score 0):

It won't work on WINDOWS

Use this :

```
   #ifndef _WINDOWS

    printf("to do in linux"); 
    //...
    #else
    printf("should work in both linux and windows and i have multiple statements in this else bolck");
  //...Other blocks of code
 #endif
```