# my C code is too awkward

Tags: c

Assume the character a,b,c,d,e represent the number 1 to 9, and they cannot be equal to 
each other.

**Question:**

How many equals that can meet `(ab * cde = adb * ce)`. 
Example:
`36 * 495 = 396 * 45`.

Here is my code,and the result is right.However,i think my code is too awkward,especially in `(if(a!=b&&a!=c&&a!=d&&a!=e&&b!=c&&b!=d&&b!=e&&c!=d&&c!=e&&d!=e&&c*d*e!=0))`

I would appreciate it if someone could give me a better solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
    int a,b,c,d,e,m,n,i=0;
    long f1,f2,f3,f4;
    for(m=11;m<=99;m++){
        a=m/10;
        b=m%10;
        if(a!=b&&a*b!=0) 
        {
            for(n=101;n<=999;n++)
            {
                c=n/100;
                d=n%100/10;
                e=n%10;
                if(a!=b&&a!=c&&a!=d&&a!=e&&b!=c&&b!=d&&b!=e&&c!=d&&c!=e&&d!=e&&c*d*e!=0)
                {
                    f1=a*10+b;
                    f2=c*100+d*10+e;
                    f3=a*100+d*10+b;
                    f4=c*10+e;
                    if(f1*f2==f3*f4) i++;
                    printf("\n%d%d*%d%d%d*=%d%d%d*%d%d\n",a,b,c,d,e,a,d,b,c,e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A couple of spaces or parentheses would be great.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Remake your `a, b, c, d, e` to an array and awkwardness may vanish

Comment: Looks like a homework problem. If it is, you could try peaking at your classmate's code. Otherwise my first suggestion is to use functions to break the program into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, instead of

```
int a,b,c,d,e;
```

Try to use

```
int numbers[5];
```

And then to check if your numbers are all different, you can use for loops

```
doubleOccurence = FALSE; /* where FALSE = 0 */
for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j < 5; j++) {
        doubleOccurence = doubleOccurence || (numbers[i] == numbers[j]);
    }
}
```

It looks a bit clearer to me.

Comment: but complexity remains same in this case

Comment: @Chirag OP wasn't bothered with complexity but with awkwardness. This code will make it easy to add `f` and `g` and is therefore cleaner.

Comment: He should have mentionned that he wanted a mathematical tweak instead of a clear algorithm then ;)

Comment: your suggestion is useful to me,thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't really iterate through a list of variables you are better off with an array of numbers like Julien mentions in his answer.

```
int nums[5];
```

replace a with nums[0], b with nums[1], etc....

But then I would go one step further to tidying up your code and call a function that takes in the array to check uniqueness:

```
if(listIsUnique(nums, 5)) // yes hardcoded the 5, but that can be sorted
{
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
bool listIsUnique(int* nums, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
            if (nums[i] == nums[j])
                return false; // return false as soon as you find a match - slightly faster :)

    return true; // if we get here its a unique list :)
}
```

Note: code is untested, there may be mistakes :o

Comment: @Zeta wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type

Comment: @JimBalter is that comment aimed at me? - I was confused by the "@ Zeta"?

Comment: Zeta said that C has no bool type but has since deleted that comment.

Comment: oh yeah... I may have written in a bit of a c++ style, you forget to switch sometimes! thanks for the clarification ;)

Comment: bool was added to C in 1999; it's now 2013. I think C style should be considered to include it by now. :-)