# Need for _Bool in C99?

Tags: c++, c

I am reading a book on C.
It says that C99 added a data type _Bool.
It is basically an int but stores only 0 or 1.
Now I do not understand why there is a need of such a data type.
We already have bool which implicitly translates to int and vice versa.
So can somebody please tell me a situation where such a data type would be useful.

PS: C++ does not seem to support such a data type as seen [here](http://ideone.com/XruQaU).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    _Bool b = false;
    if(b == 0)
        printf("FALSE");
    else
        printf("TRUE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It says that C99 added a variable _Bool

No, C99 added a built-in type called `_Bool`, which can have values of either `0` or `1`. The header, `<stdbool.h>` defines macros in which `bool` expands to `_Bool`, `false` to `0`, and  `true` to `1`.

C++, on the other hand, has a built in type called `bool`, which can have values of `true` and `false`. For compatibility, C++11 specifies that `stdbool.h` should be present, but empty. (Some C compilers provided C++'s `bool` as an extension pre-C99.)

The intention with the C99 additions was to provide the same facilities as C++, but in a way that didn't invalidate old C89 code (where plain `bool` was available as a name). In my opinion the macro solution they came up with is less than ideal, and indeed it's still quite rare to see C code which uses the boolean types, whereas they are pervasive in C++.

Answer (score 9):

`_Bool` in C doesn't have the same semantic than the other integer types.

For example, for the conversions to integers:

```
 (_Bool) 0.5
```

evaluates to `1`

whereas

```
 (int)  0.5
```

evaluates to `0`.

(This is the example given by the C99 Rationale for the `_Bool` type).

Comment: Do you know of a good source of information outlining the complete semantics?

Comment: @Dolda2000 I don't, the best is to look at the Standard directly.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Another thing with `_Bool` that you couldn't do with C89 basic integer types, is `(_Bool) integer_value` is a shorthand for `!!integer_value`.

Comment: @ouah: So you're saying that adding the new type made it possible to do in seven or nine characters something that could otherwise be done in two or four (depending upon the need to add parentheses around the following expression in either case)?

Answer (score 3):

> We already have bool

`bool` is a macro for `_Bool`. That's why we have `_Bool`. (Naming it `bool` would've broken code that already used the name; `_Bool` is less likely to collide with anything.)

Comment: User-defined names aren't allowed to start with an underscore followed by a capital letter, so `_Bool` was not just less likely to collide with anything, it was impossible (in standard compliant code).

Answer (score 2):

C++ does have a `bool` type, and so doesn't bother with `_Bool`.  Before C99, C did *not* have a `bool` type; and from C99 on the `<stdbool.h>` header defined `bool` as a macro that expanded to `_Bool`.

Comment: [Macro, not typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type).