# _Bool data type of C99

Tags: c, boolean, c99

The C99 standard of the C programming language defines the `_Bool` data type as a macro for another data type (as the language isn't able to deal with a type safe boolean).

Is the `_Bool` a macro for `unsigned char`, `unsigned int` or some other data type?

Comment: `_Bool` is a new type in C99. It's type-safe (insofaras C can be called "type-safe", that is), not an "extension of another data type" (whatever that means)

Comment: -1: C99 doesn't defines _Bool as "extension" (????) of another data type.

Comment: I thought it was a macro.

Comment: No, it's not a macro. It's a keyword. See the C99 standard 6.7.2. You're thinking of the header `stdbool.h`, in which `bool` is defined as a macro that expands to `_Bool`.

Comment: Wrong again: _Bool is not a macro. The associated macro is `bool`.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C99 boolean data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`_Bool` is a separate integer type that according to the C Standard. `_Bool` is a **keyword** of the C language.

> 2 An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values
> 0 and 1.

`_Bool` is unsigned integer type.

> The type _Bool and the unsigned integer types that correspond to the
> standard signed integer types are the standard unsigned integer types.

And there should be mentioned that

> — The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard
> integer types.

Comment: Apparently the premise of my question was wrong as I thought it was a macro. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The `_Bool` type is a new type appearing in the standard C99.
It is an unsigned integer type.
Its range of values it has to be able to hold the values 0 and 1.
The range of values of `_Bool` is contained in the range of values of any other unsigned integer type.

The keyword `_Bool` is used instead of `bool` because the standard rationale suppose that there exists in the existing practice (before 1999) several and different uses of the identifier `bool` (as a macro or well as a typedef).

The standard header `<stdbool.h>` defines the macro `bool` as meaning exactly `_Bool`.
Also, the (macro) constants `true` and `false` are defined as being 1 and 0 respectively.

Although the intent is to use the word `bool`, the programer can choose to use or not the standard type `_Bool` or well to give his own definition of `bool`.

Comment: Where does the C standard specify that the type _Bool is unsigned?

Comment: @2501: 6.2.5p.6: **The type _Bool and the unsigned integer types that  correspond  to  the  standard  signed  integer types are the standard   unsigned   integer   types.**

Comment: That was my point. _Bool is not an unsigned type. It is a separate type from unsigned integer types. _Bool is however a standard unsigned integer type.

Comment: @2501: One could have some degree of confusion if the term `standard unsigned integer type` is not considered a subset of the class of `unsigned integer types`. I think that the intent is that `_Bool` be considered an `unsigned integer type` which is, also, `standard`. On the other hand, given a `standard signed integer type` there is a corresponding `standard unsigned integer type` (like the couple `short` and `unsigned short`, for example). But clearly `_Bool` is not obtained in this way. It is an additional `standard unsigned integer type` by its own.

Comment: You're reading it backwards. Unsigned integers types are a subset of standard unsigned integer types.

Comment: @2501: Mmmmm... The implementation could define its own integer types, which won't be "standard", but "extended". At the end of 6.2.5.p.6 says: *The standard and extended unsigned integer types are collectively called unsigned integer types*.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that final quote. I guess then the standard is using the same name for defining different things. Ugh...

Comment: @2501 No, it says *"The type _Bool and the **unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer types** are the standard unsigned integer types"*.  So the "normal" unsigned integer types (those that have a corresponding signed variant), sadly, don't have a name (at least not one given by the standard).  Or one could consider that their name is the **unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer types**; a long name, but specific enough.

Answer (score 5):

C99 defines a new type `_Bool`.

It also defines a new header file `stdbool.h` that includes the line:

```
#define bool _Bool
```