# In which version of C was _Bool type introduced?

Tags: c, gcc

Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type) question on SO specify that `_Bool` was introduced in C99 (specifically 
BobbyShaftoe's answer).

But the following code compiles perfectly with `gcc -std=c90 -pedantic test.c` and `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic test.c` both, producing output `1` (my gcc version is 4.7.1)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    _Bool a = 0;
    printf("%u\n",sizeof(a) );
    return 0;
}
```

So in which version was `_Bool` introduced ?

Comment: In C99 as you mention in your question. You are confusing an individual implementation with the specification to which all implementations *should* adhere.

Comment: @SantoshA Why do you think it's not related to programming?

Comment: strictly speaking, identifiers starting with an _ are reserved for the implementation - a c89 compliant compiler might very well give you e.g. a macro or typedef called a _Bool.

Comment: @0xC0000022L by `implementation` do you mean the implementation of `gcc` compiler ?

Comment: `-std=c90 -pedantic` doesn't disable/catch *all* the extensions of gcc. GCC doc hints *Some features that are part of the C99 standard are accepted as extensions in C90 mode, and some features that are part of the C11 standard are accepted as extensions in C90 and C99 modes.* Regardless, you can be sure that bool was introduced only in ISO C99 and not before.

Comment: @Nishant: indeed. Actually that's what you imply with your question, since you give GCC and GCC only as an example for an implementation. Basically the flaw of your question is the assumption that GCC behaves perfectly true to the spec when given the flags you mention. Which, as Blue Moon pointed out, is not a good assumption.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_Bool data type of C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602814/bool-data-type-of-c99)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by @0xC0000022L you need to differentiate between standard and actual implementation. Interestingly there is however some inconsistency how GCC (and Clang as well) treats `_Bool`. C99 introduced also `_Complex` type, for which there is diagnostic message:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) (sizeof(_Complex)));
    return 0;
}
```

results into (GCC 4.4.7):

```
$ gcc -ansi -pedantic-errors check.c 
check.c: In function ‘main’:
check.c:5: error: ISO C90 does not support complex types
check.c:5: error: ISO C does not support plain ‘complex’ meaning ‘double complex’
```

You may examine source code, and then you will find that indeed `_Complex` type is checked against standard version, while `_Bool` is not:

#### `gcc/po/gcc.pot:19940`

```
#: c-decl.c:7366
#, gcc-internal-format
msgid "ISO C90 does not support complex types"
msgstr ""
```

#### `gcc/c-decl.c:7380`

```
case RID_COMPLEX:
  dupe = specs->complex_p;
  if (!flag_isoc99 && !in_system_header)
pedwarn (input_location, OPT_pedantic, "ISO C90 does not support complex types");
```

I wouldn't call it a bug, but rather a decision that was made by developers.

Comment: it is worth noting that your error is a warning in GCC 4.7.1 resulted due to the `-pedantic` flag, otherwise the codes compiles successfully with output `16`.

Comment: This is simply, as the message indicates, because gcc still supposes C90 per default and not C99.