# C syntax - error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

Why am I getting a syntax error for my C header declaration?

Here is my header file, viterbi.h:

```
#ifndef VITERBI_H
#define VITERBI_H
void vitdec(float* , int , int ,   bool* );
#endif //VITERBI_H
```

And here is my implementation file, viterbi.c:

```
// viterbi.c   : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "viterbi.h"
#include "math.h"
//void vitdec(float* sd, int frameLen, int rate,   bool* hd);

void vitdec(float* sd, int frameLen, int rate,   bool* hd)
{
    //... The rest of the function
```

The errors from the Visual Studio 2010 compiler read:

```
viterbi.h(4): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
viterbi.h(4): error C2081: 'bool' : name in formal parameter list illegal
viterbi.h(4): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
viterbi.h(4): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
viterbi.h(4): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
viterbi.c(7): error C2065: 'bool' : undeclared identifier
viterbi.c(7): error C2065: 'hd' : undeclared identifier
viterbi.c(7): warning C4552: '*' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
```

As far as I have seen/can tell, this is valid syntax for a C declaration.  If I compile viterbi.c as C++ code (viterbi.cpp), then the errors disappear.  What is the syntax error?

Comment: There is no such thing as `bool` in `C` (89).  You want to compile `C` code using Visual Studio, then you gotta write `C` code, not `C++` code.

Comment: Looks like `bool` is probably the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18042253

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: `bool` is a macro mapping to the **standard type** `_Bool`. and there are recommendations not to redefine `bool` etc. in the application. And C is not C89, but standard C, which is **only** C11.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't compile C code as C++ and vice versa. If you want to use C, don't use MSVC, it is not standard compliant. It is stuck with the 27 year old outdated version C89/90. A modern C compiler like gcc or clang does support the standard (to use `bool`, you have to `#include <stdbool.h>` accortding to the standard.

Comment: @Olaf Visual Studio was used, given the error message.  The `C` compiler that comes with Visual Studio is only C89 compliant.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That's why it should not be used for C projects. Even MISRA noticed there was a new version of the standard 17 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bool` is not a native C type, but for those using C99, try adding the line `#include <stdbool.h>`, which contains a macro that defines `bool`.

Since the C compiler in all Visual Studio/MSVC products uses C89, `bool` is not defined at all for you, as a native C type or otherwise. Workarounds include using `typedef` or `enum` to define `bool`. Examples are in the below link.

For more information, see: [Is bool a native C type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type)

Comment: The macro `bool` is not native, but it maps to the native type `_Bool` in that header by a macro (mandatory). That's because there is too much badly written C code in the wild which defines their own version of `bool` (you might be surprised how creative some ppl are how to define their own boolean type). So you can use `_Bool` as the native type (I don't recommend it though).

Comment: @Keith My VS 2010 compiler supports C89/90, so I must look for another solution.

Comment: @StephenWang That's what I mean, you need the header for the macro Olaf explained to be visible. Did you try it? Compiling on ideone.com failed without the include and succeeded with it.

Comment: @KeithM Correct, <stdbool.h> makes the _Bool macro visible.  The _Bool built-in type is only defined for C99 - see [bool-data-type-of-c99-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602814/bool-data-type-of-c99-c).  So for installations of VS 2010, neither is <stdbool.h> installed nor is _Bool a built-in type.

Comment: @StephenWang Ah, then if you think your question is not answered by the linked Duplicate, you should edit your question to explain why it is not a duplicate, and then request for it to be re-opened. :)

Comment: @Keith It has - one of the later answers provided a workaround.  What is the best way to handle this as OP?

Comment: @StephenWang I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "handle this as OP."

Comment: @StephenWang Edited based on your rejected edit. Thanks! In the future, leave a comment or new answer for drastic changes.