# Logical AND operator in c spitting out 1

Tags: c

```
int a;
scanf("%i", &a);
printf("%i", a&&1);
```

In this program, no matter the input it spits out a 1, even when I try even numbers. The only exception is when a = 0. I might not be understanding the AND operator correctly, but for any even number shouldn't the output be 0?

Comment: Changing title to "&& operator in c spitting out 1" or "logical AND operator in c spitting out 1" would make this question more valuable.

Comment: Your example invokes undefined behavior BTW due to reading an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @EdS.: Kind of. It is UB for invalid input, so you're half-right; he should check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: You need to use bit-wise comparison operator '&' to check for an odd number like:  num & 1

Comment: @TimČas: No; it's UB because he is reading the *value* of `a` in `a && 1`, yet `a` is uninitialized.  Reading an uninitialized variable is UB.

Comment: @EdS.: As I said, not for valid input. He has the `scanf` immediately before that, which initializes `a`.

Comment: @TimČas:... and so it does :). Not sure how I missed that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `&&` operator returns a non zero value if both its operands are not zero. Maybe you mean `&`.

```
int a;
if (scanf("%i", &a) == 1)
    printf("%i", a & 1);
```

- [`&&`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) is the logical `AND` operator.
- [`&`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) is the bitwise `AND` operator.

Comment: @Jongware I didn't get why you removed the `'` from `its`, but now I see... I am improving my english while participating here.

Comment: :) Aw, all you have to remember is "'s" is short for "is". [No shortage of people who do not want's to learn](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22want%27s%22) on this site.

Comment: [Pronouns just suck in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_personal_pronouns).  Particularly I/me/my/mine vs he/him/his/his vs she/her/her/hers.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `&&` is the logical AND operator that returns true/false.
In C language false is 0 (zero) otherwise 1 (one) for true as C does not have boolean type.
So the result of your operator is correct and as expected.

If you insist on using bool type you can include definition for it as below

```
// standard way
#include <stdbool.h>
```

which is basically

```
#define bool _Bool
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

Comment: "C does not have boolean type"  Hmm what is `_Bool` then?

Comment: C does have a boolean type for the past 16 years.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type

Comment: _Bool is a typedef int _Bool;

Comment: With a C99 and C11 compiler, try `printf("%d %d\n", (_Bool) 0.9,  (int) 0.9);`  this prints `"1 0"` as conversion to `_Bool` differ from conversion to `int`.  If "_Bool is a typedef int _Bool;", the same result would have occurred.

Comment: Not necessarily. The number 0.9 is not a zero (as false) then it is true (as 1). That is why integer 1 is printed. This behavior is along _Bool definition.

Comment: I found the source code for it http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/stdbool.h

Comment: @Max Zoom Yes, _Bool is not `int`.  If "_Bool was a typedef int _Bool;", then `typedef  int B; printf("%d %d\n", (B) 0.9,  (int) 0.9);` results in `"1 1"`.  But _Bool is a *not* a typedef int.  It is its own type. hence `printf("%d %d\n", (_Bool) 0.9, (int) 0.9);` reports different results.

Comment: @Max Zoom Your source indicates `#define bool _Bool #if __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L && __GNUC__ < 3 typedef int _Bool;"`.  So for old versions of C, `bool` is a typedef `int`.  Newer C, since C99, has a boolean type `_Bool` and `bool` is a macro for the C boolean type `_Bool`.