# Comparison in variable assignment

Tags: c, comparison-operators

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I couldn't find much information.
I just want to assign the result of a comparison in a variable, like this:

```
int a = 3, b = 2; // In actual code they're not integer literals
int result = a > b;
```

When compiling, `gcc` (with `-Wall`) doesn't complain, and looking at the assembly output I found it's translated to `cmp` and `setle` (or `setg` etc.). I'm wondering whether it's invalid (C) code or considered bad practice, since I see it's never used.

Comment: `In actual code they're not integer literals` what are they in original code?

Comment: The `>` and other such operators evaluate to an int, `0` or `1`.

Comment: It's valid, it's not bad practice, and [it is used](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/99eabcdd5f904e98a02184889ab84cc9d5c17a8c/libavcodec/libopenjpegdec.c#L186-L189).

Comment: @Lashane It was just to point out that `a` and `b` wouldn't be optimized out at compile time. They would be `int`s coming from functions or user input.

Comment: Thanks to all for the quick replies!

Comment: Just because they're the result of a function doesn't mean they won't be optimized out; inlining and link-time optimizations can still optimize them out. Not that it matters as long as your code is well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid C code. The behavior is detailed in section 6.5.8.6 of the C99 standard:

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=` (greater than or equal to) shall yield `1` if the specified relation is true and `0` if it is false. The result has type `int`.

Unless you are maintaining legacy code that must be compatible with pre-C99 compilers, [consider using `<stdbool.h>` and `bool` type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4767923/335858) instead of an `int`.

Answer (score -3):

What @dasblinkenlight said is right. In addition to that, and I am not aware with your code, you may need to define the variable "result" as volatile to avoid compiler optimization, where 2 and 3 are magic values and already the result of comparison is known.
So, try to replace :

```
int result = a > b;
```

with

```
volatile int result = a > b;
```

Read more about volatile usage.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid optimization

Comment: Why do you think that `volatile` might be relevant?  The value assigned to `result` will be the value of the comparison when the assignment is executed. Even if `a` or `b` (or both) subsequently change, that will not change the value in `result`, whether it is marked `volatile` or not.  Your 'read more about voltatile usage' line isn't a link, though the content suggests there should be a link there somewhere.

Comment: In case this variable used later; not assigning to it anymore just usage; this will be optimized.

Comment: for better understanding, we should have the complete code.

Comment: `volatile` actively hinders optimization. Using it will not help the code be optimized. Just the opposite.

Comment: Actually, that's what I meant to say.