# Macro - combination between function and multiplication

Tags: c, function, macros, return-value

I have the following function (`bool` is just a `#define bool int` macro):

```
bool v2dAngleRad(Vector2D* v2d1, Vector2D* v2d2, double* angle);
```

It returns the angle between two 2D vectors (the result is stored in `angle`). I have decided to use a return "boolean" value for my functions which will be used to check if the operation has been successful and only if it's `true` (in my case `#define true 1` ;)) the passed argument(s) will be checked what they contain. I was more or less forced to do that due to the possibility of some operations failing and since there are no exceptions in `C` as far as I know this seems to be the best way to tackle the situation. In `v2dAngleRad(...)` the only thing that can go wrong is if an invalid reference to `v2d1`  and/or `v2d2` is passed in which case I want to return `false`.

In addition to that I wanted to use a macro (just to refresh my memory but also to probably do stuff later on with other functions) to handle the conversion to degrees. I want to define the following macro:

```
#define v2dAngleDeg(v2d1, v2d2, angle) ... // angle*180./M_PI
```

The problem is that due to the way my function is defined (with a return value and the argument passed as a pointer to it) I am unable to figure out a way how to use `angle` in the macro definition to convert it to degrees after it has been populated by the function call. Additional check on the boolean return value also should be made and the conversion has to take place ONLY if the operation has been successful.

If my function was like this

```
double v2dAngleRad(Vector2D* v2d1, Vector2D* v2d2);
```

that is returning the angle I would have been able to do

```
#define v2dAngleDeg(v2d1, v2d2) (v2dAngleRad(v2d1, v2d2)*(180.0/M_PI))
```

I know this might seem pretty stupid and I'm actually probably going to write a separate function for this but still I would like to know how to handle such a function **in general** (doesn't matter if I handle angles or tomatoes).

Comment: I don't see any reason to use a macro here at all. Never use a macro if a function can do. If you don't trust your compiler, make the function `inline`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't even know they have included something like this in the standard libraries.

Comment: In that case you might want to first read a modern C book. `_Bool` resp. the macro `bool` is standard since 17 years. Just think what else you have missed ... e.g. `inline` functions.

Comment: @Olaf You are right but as I mentioned in the post I would simply like to know if it's possible and how to do it if it is. The radians to degree conversion was just what made me scratch my head. Nothing more. You can view that function as `int foo(int *x)`.

Comment: "I would simply like to know if it's possible" - yes, you can always shoot your foot. My comment was about good practice. SO is dedicated to enhancing code quality, not tell ppl how to - well - shoot their feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the implementation of the function is simple it is probably easier to just make a `v2dAngleRad` function that doesn't refer to `v2dAngleDeg`.  But if you do want to delegate, you can use an inline function:

```
static inline bool v2dAngleRad(Vector2D* v2d1, Vector2D* v2d2, double* angle)
{
    if ( ! v2dAngleDeg(v2d1, v2d2, angle) )
         return false;

    *angle *= 180/M_PI;
    return true;
}
```

It would be possible to use a multi-line preprocessor macro instead, however that is less robust. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137575/inline-functions-vs-preprocessor-macros) for comparison of the two approaches.

Since C99 `inline` is part of the language, but even on a C89 compiler, most of them have some sort of support for an `inline`-equivalent keyword or attribute. Of course you don't have to make it an inline function, you could put a non-inline declaration in the header and put this definition in a source file somewhere.

NB. Consider using the [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type) `#include <stdbool.h>` instead of rolling your own bool. Using `int` to hack a bool can lead to subtle bugs.