# C Program Arrays comparison

Tags: c

We have two arrays A and B, each of 10 integers. Write a function that tests if every element of array A is equal to its corresponding element in array B. In other words, the function must check if `A[0]` is equal to `B[0]`, `A[1]` is equal to `B[1]`, and so forth. The function is to return true if all elements are equal and false if at least one element is not equal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add 
   your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

bool array(int ptr1[], int ptr2[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int array1[] = {11, 33, 34, 25, 16, 2, 24, 57, 86, 66};
    int array2[] = {11, 33, 34, 25, 16, 2, 24, 57, 86, 66};

    int i;

    printf("Array A\t\tArray B\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\t\t%d\n", array1[i], array2[i]);

    printf("\nResult of comparision: \n");

    bool result = array (array1, array2);

    if(result == 1)
        printf("false\n");
    else
        printf("false\n");
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

The errors that I get are:

> ```
> main.c(.text+0xfa): undefined 'array'
> [Error]  Id returned 1 exit status
> recipe for target '"Problem' failed
> ```

Comment: `bool` is defined in `stdbool.h` for C99.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C99 boolean data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type)

Comment: I see where you give a (forward) *declaration* for `array()`, but I don't see where you *define* it (i.e., write it's body).  Is there another source file you need to include when compiling? (or use `-c` to compile without linking?)

Comment: You were given this function prototype: `bool array(int ptr1[], int ptr2[]);`, and you should now implement this function. Your code assumes that it already exists somewhere, but it doesn't - that's why you were given this task.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have **declared** `array`:

```
bool array(int ptr1[], int ptr2[]);
```

but not **defined** it. When you link, the linker looks for the definition of function `array` and cannot find one, prompting the error:

```
main.c(.text+0xfa): undefined 'array'
[Error]  Id returned 1 exit status
recipe for target '"Problem' failed
```

To *define* the function at same point your *declare* it, you must add the body of the function. In that case, there is no need for a *forward declaration*. It has been declared before its use in `main`, e.g.

```
int arraycmp (int ptr1[], int ptr2[], size_t size)
{
    return memcmp (ptr1, ptr2, size);
}
```

(**note:** regardless of whether you use `memcmp` or simply loop over each element and perform a single comparison for each, you must pass the number of elements as a parameter)

If on the other hand, you do not *define* the function until after `main()`, then the *forward declaration* is required so that the function is usable in `main()`.

Putting it altogether, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add 
   your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int arraycmp (int ptr1[], int ptr2[], size_t size)
{
    return memcmp (ptr1, ptr2, size);
}

int main (void) {

    int array1[] = {11, 33, 34, 25, 16, 2, 24, 57, 86, 66},
        array2[] = {11, 33, 34, 25, 16, 2, 24, 57, 86, 66},
        i;

    printf("Array A\t\tArray B\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("  %d\t\t  %d\n", array1[i], array2[i]);

    printf("\nResult of comparision: %s\n", 
        arraycmp (array1, array2, sizeof array1) ? "false" : "true");

#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
    getchar();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** if there is any chance your arrays differ in number of elements, you should check before calling `arraycmp` and handle the error as you wish. Either return exiting that point or pass the size of the smaller and only compare that initial number of elements)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrcmp
Array A         Array B
  11              11
  33              33
  34              34
  25              25
  16              16
  2               2
  24              24
  57              57
  86              86
  66              66

Result of comparision: true
```

Changing `57` to `56` in `array2`,

```
$ ./bin/arrcmp
Array A         Array B
  11              11
  33              33
  34              34
  25              25
  16              16
  2               2
  24              24
  57              56
  86              86
  66              66

Result of comparision: false
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.