# Fastest boolean representation in C

Tags: c, types, boolean

In C language code, if I have a bunch of variables that will be used only for logical operations, what is the data type that will yield the fastest execution time?

Also, does it depend if I'm using an ARM or Intel processor, 32-bit or 64-bit system?

Comment: premature micro-optimisation?

Comment: Make a typedef, then benchmark. Best way to know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1921557

Comment: Just use `_Bool` and if you find that too slow then that's when you should consider optimisations.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that C has "execution time"? This is a concept that comes from implementations of the C language, not from the C language. Your question is a bit like "What is the fastest accent, tone and/or volume to speak English in?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the compiler allows, include `<stdbool.h>`, use `bool`, and trust the compiler/RTL vendor to do the right thing. Otherwise use `int`.