# My linux's gcc compiler not supporting boolean values

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, boolean

I'm trying to make a function with return type as boolean...the syntax of the program seems to be correct but the compiler is giving errors....

The header files I've included are:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

the function I've created is:

```
34.bool checknull(struct node* node){
35.    if ( node != NULL )
36.        return TRUE;
37.       
38.    return false;
39.}
```

and what I'm getting at compile time is

```
bininsertion.c:34:1: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
bininsertion.c: In function ‘checknull’:
bininsertion.c:36:10: error: ‘TRUE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bininsertion.c:36:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each  function it appears in
bininsertion.c:38:9: error: ‘false’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I've tried "TRUE,false" both in small and capital letters but doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Possibly duplacated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should include `<stdbool.h>` if you want `bool`, `true` and `false`. Also it's `true`, not `TRUE`.

---

If you don't want to include `stdbool.h` you can just use the slightly ugly `_Bool`.

Comment: including stdbool.h solves my problem...thanx for that...and can you please explain the slightly ugly part i.e. how to use "_Bool" ( Syntax and an example )...

Comment: @Sabre.Tooth Use it like a normal type. So wherever you would write `bool` you could also write `_Bool`. The fact is `_Bool` is the "real" type, introduced in C99 and `bool` is just an alias. They couldn't introduce `bool` since it wasn't a reserved keyword in previous standards so it would have broken programs already using it.

Comment: using _Bool I still have to include stdbool.h because compiler treats "true" and "false" as undeclared variables...thnxxx for the help...

Comment: @Sabre.Tooth Yeah, or you can use `1` and `0`. But by all means, I recommend `stdbool.h`.

Answer (score -1):

### Original Answer

<s>Try include cstdio and cstdlib. Might not make any difference, but I've been noticing these weird errors with my compiler also. Things that used to work, no longer work</s>

### Edit

In C, false is represented by 0, while true is represented by anything non zero.

In essence, you can roll your own `bool` datatype like this

```
typedef enum {false, true} bool;
```

Then you can use it just like you have already in your app.

You can also just include `stdbool.h` which should have something similar to the enum suggestion

Answer (score -1):

bool is not a data type.. 
It works fine in Visual studio.. cause its a Microsoft-Specific thingy.. 
Just include `stdbool.h` and it will work fine :)

Comment: aha.. I just made some search.. bool is a datatype in C++.. :) the edit button isn't workin though..