# Error using strcmp with char and struct arrays

Tags: c, strcmp

I have a program in which I have an array of 10 `struct` variables called `students`. Within `students` I have a `char` array variable called `testAnswers` with 20 elements. What I am trying to do is to compare these ten students' `testAnswers` with a `char` array variable called `answers` with 20 elements. Basically, variable `answers` is the answer sheet for the students' `testAnswers`. The answers are all true/false. This is what I have so far:

Note: `numStu` is 10 and `numAns` is 20.

```
void checkAnswers(char  answers[], student students[]){

for (int i = 0 ; i < numStu ; i++){
for (int d = 0 ; d < numAns ; d++){

if (students[i].testAnswers[d] == ' '){
          students[i].score += 1 ; //if the student did not answer the question add 1     which will be substracted once if loop sees it is not correct resulting in the         student losing 0 points.                   
                               }
  if (strcmp(answers[d],students[i].testAnswers[d]) == 0){
              students[i].score +=2 ;//if the student answer is correct add 2 points    to score
              }
  if (strcmp(answers[d],students[i].testAnswers[d]) != 0){
              students[i].score -= 1 ; //if the student answer is incorrect substrct 1    point
              }

}//end inner for
}//end for outer
  }//end checkAnswers
```

The errors I continue to receive:

```
invalid conversion from char to const char
initializing argument 1 of `int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'
```

For both instances where I used `strcmp`. I am wondering if there is anyway to correct this error or any better way to compare these two chars and score the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcmp` is to compare to **strings** (sequences of characters), not **single characters**.

You can just use an equality check for single characters:

```
if (answers[d] == students[i].testAnswers[d])
```

Note that if we're talking about boolean values, using [an explicit boolean type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c) is probably better than `char`.