# expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before func

Tags: c, linux, unix, linux-device-driver

I have the following function with me
and when i compile my entire file it gives me a certain error:

Function:

```
static boolean
2388 e1000_phys_port (pic_t *pic, e1000_t *e1000)
2389 {
2390         pic->pic_flags = 0;
2391 
2392         switch (pic->pic_id) {
2393         case I2C_ID_VSERIES_GIGE_PIC:
2394                 e1000->e1000_port_count = fwdd_vjx_get_e1000_ports();
2395                 break;
2396         default:
2397                 syslog(LOG_ERR, "%s: unknown I2C ID\n", e1000->pic_name);
2398                 return(FALSE);
2399         }
2400 
2401         return(TRUE);  
2402 }
```

Error:

```
2388: error:expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before e1000_phys_port
```

If anyone could resolve this for me asap!

Comment: What is the definition of `boolean`?

Comment: `boolean` is [not a type in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c). (Unless you `typedef`'ed it somewhere yourself)

Comment: should i add typedef before static?

Comment: What @RussellZahniser means is that there's no type named `boolean` in C, unless it was defined using `typedef` (or `#define`), for example `typedef int boolean;`.

Comment: You should `#include <stdbool.h>` and use the return type `bool`, if you can.

Comment: +1 for posting line numbers

Comment: use can `typedef char boolean;`

Answer (score 0):

`boolean` is [not a type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c). (Unless you `typedef`'ed it somewhere yourself) –  Russell Zahniser

What @RussellZahniser means is that there's no type named `boolean` in C, unless it was defined using `typedef` (or `#define`), for example `typedef int boolean;`. –  caspase

You should `#include <stdbool.h>` and use the return type `bool`, if you can. –  Klas Lindbäck