# Bool *X,What data type is this?

Tags: c

So the question in one of my assignments is: ..

A function whose signature is

`int int2seq( bool* X, int8_t x );`

that should extract and then store each i-th bit of x in the i-th element of array X; it should return the
total number of elements stored.

---

my Question is What is the `bool* X` I've never come across it before,it sounds like a boolean value,but is it supposed to behave like an array?

Comment: `*` denotes a pointer, thus `bool*` is a pointer to boolean. You'll want to read up on pointers. Since C allows pointer arithmetic, yes, `bool*` can also be used to denote the start (or any position within) an array of booleans.

Comment: You should read a basic introductory to C. In particular you need to read about arrays, pointers, `bool` or `_Bool` and fixed width integer types. The `8` in `int8_t` is a hint how big the array is expected to be, but actually your teacher chose the wrong type it should merely be `uint8_t`. Voting to close because too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c) it will help you to understand bool in C.
In your case `bool *X` pointer to bool array is what I understand. But it also can point to single variable also.