# using bool in c (within a structure)

Tags: c

I wanted to use a boolean variable in c as a flag,within a structure,but c does not have any keyword "bool" to make it possible.
I got some relevant information here :  [Using boolean values in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c)
**then basically,I tried this**

```
struct bookshop
{
    char name[20];
    char issuer[20];
    int id;
    typedef enum { false, true } flag;

};
```

**to get the following error,on this line:"typedef enum { false, true } flag";**
Multiple markers at this line
    - expected specifier-qualifier-list before 
     ‘typedef’
    - Type 'flag' could not be resolved
    - Syntax error

please help!
and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use the `typedef` before the struct declaration and define a var of the type in the struct.

Comment: You can only declare member variables inside structures, not type-aliases. Also since the C99 standard [C have a boolan type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) that you can use.

Comment: C99 introduced the `_Bool` keyword for boolean types.

Answer (score 6):

You can't put a `typedef` inside of a struct definition like that.  It needs to be at the global level.

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;

struct bookshop
{
    char name[20];
    char issuer[20];
    int id;
    bool flag;
};
```

If you have `stdbool.h` available, you can just include that and it will provide the `bool` type as well as the `true` and `false` constants.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to declare the variable of type `enum`, inside the structure definition you should not use `typedef`.

The `typedef` is used to define a type, a user defined type and that's not what you want, you want to declare a variable which in turn is a member of the structure, so

```
struct bookshop
{
    char name[20];
    char issuer[20];
    int id;
    enum { false, true } flag;    
};
```

should do it.

Also note, that there is a standard header *stdbool.h* so that you can do this

```
struct bookshop
{
    char name[20];
    char issuer[20];
    int id;
    bool flag;    
};
```

Comment: Note in the first alternative that the `true` and `false` enumeration constants are defined, but no other variable of that type can ever be defined because there is neither an enumeration tag name nor a typedef for it.  I was debating whether to add an answer about that; now I don't have to.  Also, in the original, if the `typedef` had been allowed, it would have introduced a type name `flag` and would not have created a member at all.  It actually isn't allowed, so that isn't a problem in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a new type in a declaration. You first have to declare the bool typedef and then you can use it your struct, i.e.:

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;

struct bookshop
{
    char name[20];
    char issuer[20];
    int id;
    bool flag;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the int type was used to hold 'boolean' values: **true** for non zero values, and **false** for zero ones.

Since C99, you could use the macros and values defined in **stdbool.h**:

> bool  _Bool
>
> true  integer constant 1
>
> false     integer constant 0
>
> __bool_true_false_are_defined  integer constant 1

But be aware of compatibility with old code, and the way standard C tests values as true or false. As explained before, following code:

```
int flag = 4;

if(flag) {
     puts("true\n");
}
else {
     puts("false\n");
}
```

will print `true`.