# Why use <stdbool.h> instead of _Bool?

Tags: c, boolean, stdbool

Any time I had the need of a Boolean type I was told to either create one, or better yet, use `stdbool.h`.

Since `stdbool.h` uses `typedef bool _Bool`, is there a reason to use the header instead just using type `_Bool`? Is it just for the additional macros (`/* #define true 1     #define false 0 */`)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The obvious type to add into the language was `bool`. But unfortunately, plenty of code was written that included `bool` in other shapes and forms. Recall that support for a boolean type was added only in C99.

So the C language committee had no choice but to pull out a reserved identifier for it (`_Bool`). But, since the obvious choice of type name is still the same, `stdbool.h` was added to allow users the obvious name. That way, if your code didn't have a home-brewed `bool`, you could use the built in one.

So do indeed use `stdbool.h` if you aren't bound to some existing home-brewed `bool`. It will be the standard type, with all the benefits that type brings in.

Comment: Answer which actually gives the true reason: backward compatibility with already written code. Now: what are the examples of `other shapes and forms` of `bool` that were used in plenty of code?

Comment: @pmor - I worked at a shop that had its own basic const header that contained `typedef int bool;` - and it was all over the (entirely) C90 code base.  Basically, many places would do one of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the example. Surely, it was asked before, but: why not standardizing `bool` type from the beginning (C89)? (So people had to redefine it over and over.)

Comment: @pmor - C was in widespread use for over a decade before being standardized. The first standard was likely meant to be a common baseline that folks could adopt. It couldn't have been added then either.

Answer (score 5):

The common practice has always been to use `bool` but when the type was officially introduced into the standard in C99, they didn't want to break the "roll-your-own" implementations. So they made the type `_Bool` as kind of a hack around the unofficial `bool`s. Now there's no type name collision. Anyway, point is, use `bool` unless a legacy codebase breaks.

Answer (score 4):

They are same. `bool` is an alias for `_Bool`.
Before C99 we used we dont have this type. (Earlier the use was limited to an integer tyoe with 0 as false and 1 as true).

You may not use it. Even you can `undef` `bool` (but it is recommended not to do so). **But including it (`stdbool.h` and `bool` alias of `_Bool`) is good because then if someday it becomes  reserved your code complies to that.**<sup>1</sup>

<sub>**1.** You can use `bool` other way but it is better not to. Because in general when this `stdbool.h` is introduced it bears the plan of gradually making it standard and then even more stricter rule applies where we can't use `bool` as something other and it will be **reserved as keyword**.</sub>

Comment: I know they are the same... that is why I asked. I'll edit my question to clarify

Comment: @CIsForCookies.: I just tried to say that you can use bool otherway but it is better not to. Because in general when this `stdbool.h`is introduced it bears the plan of gradually making it standard and then even more stricter rule applies where we can't use `bool` as something other and it will be reserved as keyword.

Comment: If you used `_Bool` in C90 code, you were cheating because the name was reserved for use by the implementation. Before C99, the standard C had no Boolean type; the nearest approximation was an integer type with zero as false and any non-zero value as true.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: ok I see..so before _Bool was not introduced it was introduced much later. But I saw code which used it..maybe it is used against the pratice? I edited now.