# Why do I ge a segmentation Fault when I run this function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, flags, getopt

Why do I get a segmentation fault when I send the flags -h or -H.

```
bool parse_command(int argc, char **argv, bool *header, char **fileName)
{

    if (!argv)
        return false;

    bool *flagh = false;
    bool *flagH = false;

    char *options = "Hh";
    int opt = 0;

    while ( (opt = getopt(argc, argv, options ) ) != -1)
    {
        printf("HELLO");
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'h': 
                *flagh = true; 
                break;
            case 'H':
                *flagH = true; 
                break;
            default:
                usage_p1();  
                return false;
        }

    }
    printf("%d", opt);
    // Implement this function
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `bool` and `true` is not keywords in C. Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: The asterisk in front of `flagh` suggest that it's a pointer - that you don't allocate.

Comment: This souldn't even compile, or at least not without warnings. flagh and flagH are pointers to booleans, but they don't point to anything. You don't have any actual booleans in memory. You then assign them (the pointers) to "false", which essentially make them point to memory address 0, thus the segfault.

Comment: You define two variables that are *pointers* but your initialization of them doesn't make them point to a valid location. It seems to me that those variable should *not* be pointers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I cannot see a single global?

Comment: Turn on all warnings on your compiler. Read the warnings. They should give you a hint about what's wrong.

Comment: @klutt You are right but it is unimportant.:)

Comment: @klutt They are, however, defined in `stdbool.h`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons yes, but they are no keywords, the are just macros that have the value of 0 and 1.

Comment: @Pablo Well `true` is defined as `1`, but `bool` is defined as `_Bool` which is a keyword.  Regardless, keyword or not, they are pretty well-defined values and their existence specifically as keywords don't really matter here and don't really indicate the use of c++.

Answer (score 6):

These two lines are your problem:

```
bool *flagh = false;
bool *flagH = false;
```

You're declaring `flagh` and `flagH` as *pointers* to booleans, but they don't point anywhere yet.  In fact they point definitively nowhere, since your initializations are equivalent to

```
bool *flagh = NULL;
bool *flagH = NULL;
```

You probably don't want these to be pointers.  Change the declarations to

```
bool flagh = false;
bool flagH = false;
```

Change the assignments to

```
flagh = true; 

flagH = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

```
bool *flagh = false;
bool *flagH = false;
```

Both variables are pointers, you initialize them with `false`. There are no
`true` or `false` in C, instead something is considered `false` when it
evaluates to 0, and something is considered `true` when it isn't `false`.

If this is true C code, then it would be the same as doing

```
bool *flagh = NULL;
bool *flagH = NULL;
```

Later on you do

```
*flagh = true;
```

which is dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, which is undefined and will result in a
segfault.

To fix your code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool flagh = false;
bool flagH = false;
```

and then late

```
flagh = true;
flagH = true;

// or

flagh = false;
flagH = false;
```

Like many said in the comments, C doesn't have a true boolean type. See: [Using boolean values in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c)

**edit**

Nowadays there is [`stdbool.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdbool.h.html) which declares a type `bool` and `true` and
`false`, but all is doing is redefining `true` as 1 and `false` as 0:

> [stdbool.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ginclude/stdbool.h)
>
> ```
> #ifndef _STDBOOL_H
> #define _STDBOOL_H
>
> #ifndef __cplusplus
>
> #define bool  _Bool
> #define true  1
> #define false 0
>
> #else /* __cplusplus */
>
> /* Supporting _Bool in C++ is a GCC extension.  */
> #define _Bool bool
>
> #if __cplusplus < 201103L
> /* Defining these macros in C++98 is a GCC extension.  */
> #define bool  bool
> #define false false
> #define true  true
> #endif
>
> #endif /* __cplusplus */
>
> /* Signal that all the definitions are present.  */
> #define __bool_true_false_are_defined 1
>
> #endif    /* stdbool.h */
> ```