# How to return a boolean in C?

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to create a function which should return true or false if a given number complies with the given conditions. Anyway, it doesn't seem to work.
Here's the code:

```
bool conditions(int i) {                                            
    return (i != '\n' & i != ' ' & i != '\t' & i != EOF) ? true : false;
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you included `stdbool.h`? Be more specific on how it doesn't work.

Comment: Never heard of that... Have I to use it when i use bools?

Comment: If you want to use `bool`, yes you need `stdbool.h`.  It contains the necessary macros that define `bool`.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot! Anyway, when I use, for instance, conditions(1), the compiler gives me the error " conflicting types for 'conditions' "

Comment: @LollolCat the conflicting types problem is probably because you don't declare or define the function before use.

Comment: Not entirely since the funtion doesn't work even if I've included stdbool.h

Comment: `stdbool.h` makes `bool` into an alias (a macro) for the reserved keyword `_Bool`.

Comment: @anastaciu ok, now it does work. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `stdbool.h` library  (`#include <stdbool.h>`) or define type yourself.
[answer to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c)

Comment: A "Vote to close as duplicate" is more appropriate.

Comment: I can't find button to close as duplicate (even tried search for it in stack forum). @SergeyA I though that helps if I linked post where everyone can find answer. That's why you downvote me? Hm...

Comment: @Kawson The _close_ button is a gray little text (not even looking like a button) under the question. If you don't have rep to vote to close you can make a comment: "Does _link to the duplicate_ answer your question?"

Comment: @TedLyngmo okey, I don't have this option yet, will remember next time