# error: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void [-Werror] Corne keyboard Compile problem

Tags: compiler-errors, void, qmk, qmk-firmware

I have a [Corne](https://github.com/foostan/crkbd) keyboard and I'm trying to create the .hex file. The problem is when I try to compile (`-km gotham`), it throws this:

> 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void [-Werror]

and this

> note: declared here 
> bool oled_task_user(void) {

This the part of the code:

```c
bool oled_task_user(void) {
    if (timer_elapsed(oled_timer) > 10000) {
        oled_off();
        return;
    }
    #ifndef SPLIT_KEYBOARD
    else {
        oled_on();
    }
    #endif

    if (is_keyboard_master()) {
        render_status_main();
    } else {
        render_status_secondary();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which line has a `return` with no value to return?

Comment: the weird thing is it tells me is between #endif and if (is_keyboard_master())

Answer (score 1):

*Updated 2023-06-16:*

The signature for this function appears to have been updated with a clearer enum-based return value. It is now ([code link](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/94311e4dc27e603b6c421d2773a5f82275a24411/drivers/oled/oled_driver.h#L351)):

```c
oled_rotation_t oled_init_user(oled_rotation_t rotation);
```

where `oled_rotation_t` indicates the desired rotation of the display, one of:

```c
typedef enum {
    OLED_ROTATION_0   = 0,
    OLED_ROTATION_90  = 1,
    OLED_ROTATION_180 = 2,
    OLED_ROTATION_270 = 3, // OLED_ROTATION_90 | OLED_ROTATION_180
} oled_rotation_t;
```

Update your QMK set up ([instructions](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/newbs_git_using_your_master_branch?id=updating-your-master-branch)) to get the latest.

---

*Original answer:*

The fourth line is a `return` with no value:

```c
bool oled_task_user(void) {
    if (timer_elapsed(oled_timer) > 10000) {
        oled_off();
        return;  // <--- Here.
    }
```

Replace that line with `return false;` to fix the error.

Comment: Is there any qmk documentation what `true` and `false` returns mean in the `oled_task_user` function? Couldn't find any.

Comment: @vii: It may or may not be implicit by [using C99 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c/54724724#54724724). (That is ***not*** a definite statement in any way, but more like a starting point for further research.)

Comment: @vii it looks like the `oled_init_user()` API was recently updated, and the meaning of its return value is now clearer. Please see my updated answer.