# I want to get the array elements from the user without knowing it's array size at first. I used scanf logic.But I ain't able to print value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[1000], i, n = 0;
    while (89) {
        if (scanf("%d", &i) == -1)
            break;
        arr[n] = i;
        n++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d", arr[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to get array elements at run time without knowing it's  array size.So I used scanf.scanf will return -1 if there is nothing to scanf .I don't know what is mistake in my logic. This code doesn't  print anything.

Comment: How do you tell your program that "there is nothing to scanf"?

Comment: The user needs to type the EOF character (Ctl-d on Unix, Ctl-z on Windows), to indicate the end of the input.

Comment: `while(89)` -- why `89`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c

Comment: @JAISHREEDEVAKI T, is the input all on one line or many lines?  What signifies the end of input, a linefeed, end-of-file or both or what?

Comment: This could be a good opportunity to practice implementing a linked list.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- if the user enters more than 1000 numbers, you will store the next ones beyond the end of the array, causing undefined behavior.  If the program is not expected to handle an arbitrary number of entries, you can use a fixed size array but you should test the index to avoid undefined behavior on unexpectedly long input. If the program is expected to handle arbitrarily large quantities, you have to allocate and reallocate the array as more numbers are read, using `malloc()` and `realloc()`.
- `while (89)` is an infinite loop, just like `while (1)`... a more idiomatic way to write such a loop without a magic number such as `89` is `for (;;)`
- `if (scanf("%d", &i) == -1)` is not a reliable way to check the user input: if they type anything that cannot be parsed as an integer, `scanf` will return `0`, causing the loop to iterate continuously, storing indeterminate values into the array until `n` reaches the value `1000` and the undefined behavior describe hereabove will hit an likely cause a program failure.
- `printf("%d", arr[j]);` does not separate the numbers in the output stream. This may be intended, but if not you should output a separator such as a space or a newline.

Here is a modified version of your code with the same limitation to 1000 values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[1000], val, n;
    for (n = 0; n < 1000 && scanf("%d", &val) == 1; n++)
        arr[n] = val;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an alternative that can handle arbitrary amounts, only limited by available memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *arr = NULL, val;
    size_t allocated = 0, n = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &val) == 1) {
        if (n == allocated) {
            size_t new_allocated = allocated + allocated / 2 + 32;
            int *new_arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) * new_allocated);
            if (new_arr == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate space for %zu entries\n", new_allocated);
                free(arr);
                return 1;
            }
            arr = new_arr;
            allocated = new_allocated;
        }
        arr[n++] = val;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is correct. `scanf` returns -1, when there is nothing to read (**EOF**). You can see that your code works when:

- You input your numbers and then you press CTRL+D on Linux, or CTRL+Z on Windows.
- Redirect file to your program. On Linux you can do `./myprogram < input file`.

I also want to add, that `while(89)` can be substituted for `while(scanf("%d", &i) != -1)`.