Why is free() causing an error here without the else block?
This is the full code I have right now. I have tried everything that I could think of, but when I have the contents of the else block, despite the code skipping through it, the code runs smoothly with no memory leaks.
The code doesn't pass through the else block, so it's useless to what I can see, but if I empty or remove the else block, the __debugbreak triggers on free inside DeleteSedex.
What causes this to happen?
sedex.h:
#ifndef KAAL_SEDEX_H
#define KAAL_SEDEX_H
#include "limits.h"
#ifdef ULLONG_MAX
#include "assert.h"
#include "crtdbg.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define MEMORY_UNINITIALIZED (size_t)(0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC)
#define MEMORY_AVAILABLE(ptr) (assert(NULL != ptr && MEMORY_UNINITIALIZED != (size_t)(ptr)))

typedef char* string;
typedef long long llong;
typedef enum { true, false } bool;

typedef struct sedecimstruct {
    size_t length;
    llong* content;
} *sedex;

sedex CreateSedex(string source);
void DeleteSedex(sedex target);
#endif
#endif

sedex.c:
#include "sedex.h"

int main(void)
{
    sedex n = CreateSedex("+");
    DeleteSedex(n);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}

sedex CreateSedex(string source)
{
    struct sedecimstruct output;
    bool sgned = source[0] == '+' || source[0] == '-';
    if (source == NULL || strlen(source) == 0 ||
        strlen(source) == 1 && sgned)
    {
        output.length = 2;
        output.content = calloc(output.length, sizeof(llong));
    }
    else
    {
        size_t digits = strlen(source) - sgned,
            mod = digits & 0xf;
        bool excess = mod > 0;
        output.length = (digits >> 4) + excess + 1;
        output.content = malloc(output.length * sizeof(llong));
        output.content[0] = source[0] == '-';
        char sedecim[17] = { 0 };
        MEMORY_AVAILABLE(output.content);
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= digits; i++)
        {
            sedecim[(i - 1) & 0xf] = source[i - 1 + sgned];
            if ((i & 0xf) == 0)
            {
                output.content[i >> 4] = atoll(sedecim);
                memset(sedecim, 0, sizeof(sedecim));
                continue;
            }
            if (i == digits && excess)
            {
                output.content[output.length - 1] = atoll(sedecim);
                memset(sedecim, 0, sizeof(sedecim));
            }
        }
    }
    return &output;
}

void DeleteSedex(sedex target)
{
    free(target->content); // breakpoint triggers here when else is empty or removed
    target->content = target->length = NULL;
}


You are returning a pointer to a local variable. Using it outside the function is undefined behavior.

@0___________ windows.h defines char* as LPSTR (long pointer to a string). Anyway, it's for my readability, and it's irrelevant to this problem.

Okay, I get it now. I cannot return &output. I must allocate a pointer with malloc first, and return that.
// struct sedecimstruct output;
sedex output = malloc(sizeof(struct sedecimstruct));
// ... do something to the output ...
return output;


Don't forget to free it as well, after you freed the content.

Is this a typo?
typedef enum { true, false } bool;

Usually it is:
typedef enum { false, true } bool;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921557/26993270

That's a good catch, but does not constitute an answer. And yeah, "usually" one should include the standard bool type via stdbool.h

Ah, I didn't notice that, that was embarrassing

I would've added a comment to the question, but I do not have enough reputation points to do that.

In C23, true, false and bool are full keywords — your code is not future-proof.  Including <stdbool.h> becomes irrelevant but otherwise harmless in C23.
