# error: ‘TRUE’ was not declared in this scope pad.pvx*= -1; }

Tags: c, programming-languages

```
void move_paddle(PADDLE pad, bool alongX)
{
    if(alongX!=TRUE)
    {
        if((pad.py+pad.length/2)>=B || (pad.py-pad.length/2)<=BB)
            pad.pvx*= -1;
    }
    else if((pad.px+pad.length/2)>=A || (pad.py-pad.length/2)<=AA)
            pad.pvx*= -1;
}
```

What is the actual error ? M unable to get through.

Comment: No idea if this is related to your problem, but don't compare with TRUE in C. FALSE is 0, and TRUE is usually 1, but any nonzero number will evaluate to true in an if condition. `if(!alongX)` is better, since you seem to have defined a `bool` somewhere.

Comment: Probably duplicates [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like an int instead of a bool in c, and as long as it's value ain't 0 it's true, I would change this to

```
void move_paddle(PADDLE pad, int alongX)
{
    if(!alongX)
    {
        if((pad.py+pad.length/2)>=B || (pad.py-pad.length/2)<=BB)
            pad.pvx*= -1;
    }
    else if((pad.px+pad.length/2)>=A || (pad.py-pad.length/2)<=AA)
            pad.pvx*= -1;
}
```

Comment: also, in C, this function is useless as you don't have references and your code don't use pad as a pointer (PADDLE *pad), and you use a period (.) to access you'r structures fields...

Answer (score 2):

There is no `TRUE` keyword in standard C language. Most probably, this is a macro declaration that you are missing. Where to get it depends on what compiler and libraries you are using. If you cannot find its definition, putting this code before the usage of TRUE (in the beginning of the file, but after all includes) will fix the problem:

```
#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE (0)
#endif
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE (!FALSE)
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `bool` data type, looks like you are using `stdbool.h` in C99. If that is the case then you should change `TRUE` to `true` which expands to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that if the compiler says your error is that TRUE is not declared in this scope, then that's the actual error. Maybe you should define TRUE. Also, as I pointed out in my comment (before I had looked at the title) you're probably better off not even using `TRUE` in this snippet anyway. Comparing vs. `TRUE` in C is likely to lead to subtle errors that are hard to debug. `if (!alongX)` means what you wanted to say, and I find it clearer than `if (alongX == FALSE)`.