# How to use boolean datatype in C?

Tags: c, types, boolean

I was just writing code in C and it turns out it doesn't have a boolean/bool datatype. Is there any C library which I can include to give me the ability to return a boolean/bool datatype?

Comment: Usually a plain old 'int' is used, with the assumption that 0 is 'false' and anything else is 'true'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is bool a native C type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you have a compiler that supports C99 you can

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Otherwise, you can define your own if you'd like.  Depending on how you want to use it (and whether you want to be able to compile your code as C++), your implementation could be as simple as:

```
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

In my opinion, though, you may as well just use `int` and use zero to mean false and nonzero to mean true.  That's how it's usually done in C.

Comment: @James, it worked. But what i should return? i mean 0 or false?

Comment: @ysap: I picked macros because it's closer to what C99 does (In C99, `true` and `false` are both macros that are replaced by `1` and `0`, respectively, and `bool` is a macro that expands to the boolean type, `_Bool`.

Comment: @its:  If you define macros for `bool`, `true`, and `false`, then make your return type `bool` and return `false`.  Otherwise, just make your return type `int` and return `0`.  It's up to you waht you want to do.  I just think the non-macro approach is better.

Comment: @James - sorry, I messed up with this comment, erasing it while editing, so I reposted it as an answer. You were too fast to reply...

Comment: I actually prefer in C to use 0 as false and non-zero as true w/o a specific type.  In other cases where the call might fail, 0 is success and NZ is an error code (usually negative codes).

Answer (score 18):

C99 has a boolean datatype, actually, but if you must use older versions, just define a type:

```
typedef enum {false=0, true=1} bool;
```

Comment: If you ask me, "emulating" `bool` pre-C99 is dangerous because the semantics differ. `(bool)2` yields 2, not 1. A more realistic example: `1U<<(bool)isdigit(c)` will give the wrong result on most implementations.

Answer (score 5):

C99 has a `bool` type.  To use it,

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: James McNellis's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4159725/369450) already says to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to James McNellis answer, I always try to use enumeration for the bool type instead of macros: `typedef enum bool {false=0; true=1;} bool;`. It is safer b/c it lets the compiler do type checking and eliminates macro expansion races

Comment: This doesn't prevent you from saying `bool b = 1;`

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no additional type checking over what you would get with a `#define bool int`.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. However, you are talking about the variable declaration, while I am relating to the actual usage of the true and false tokens.

Comment: Can you give an example of where additional type checking is done?

Comment: Well, its hard indeed, but just an example: `float f; f = true;` should raise a warning for the implicit (and supposedly incompatible) type cast.

Comment: @Paul - I'm curious - are you sure this is a problem? If my memory serves me right, then enums are treated as ints. Ain't so? If you are right then this is definitely a good counter-example.

Comment: @ysap: you're quick ! I deleted that comment almost immediately because I wasn't sure if I had remembered the problem exactly - I've just been trying to recreate an issue I know I had a while back with enums and ++ but it's still eluding me.

Answer (score 0):

C99 introduced `_Bool` as intrinsic pure boolean type. No `#include`s needed:

```
int main(void)
{
  _Bool b = 1;
  b = 0;
}
```

On a true C99 (or higher) compliant C compiler the above code should compile perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

We can use enum type for this.We don't require a library.
For example

```
           enum {false,true};
```

the value for `false` will be 0 and the value for `true` will be 1.

Answer (score -3):

```
struct Bool {
    int true;
    int false;
}

int main() {

    /* bool is a variable of data type – bool*/
    struct Bool bool;

    /*below I’m accessing struct members through variable –bool*/ 
    bool = {1,0};
    print("Student Name is: %s", bool.true);
    return 0;
}
```