# Which header file do you include to use bool type in C?

Tags: c, boolean

Here's all .h files I've included so far,but non have the definition of `bool`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <event.h>
```

Which file does define `bool`?

Comment: I'd simply use `int` just like everybody did before C99 :)

Comment: or simply use _Bool and reveal your true intent . . . ;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's part of [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) and defined in [POSIX definition stdbool.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html).

Comment: tere's a more recent version of POSIX specification at [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Comment: It is not a POSIX definition, it is an ISO C header.  POSIX has nothing to do with it other than POSIX is a superset of teh standard library.  Suggest https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types

Answer (score 46):

`#include <stdbool.h>`

For someone like me here to copy and paste.

Answer (score 18):

`bool` is **just a macro** that expands to `_Bool`. You can use `_Bool` with no `#include` very much like you can use `int` or `double`; it is a C99 keyword.

The macro is defined in `<stdbool.h>` along with 3 other macros.

The macros defined are

- `bool`: macro expands to `_Bool`
- `false`: macro expands to `0`
- `true`: macro expands to `1`
- `__bool_true_false_are_defined`: macro expands to `1`

Answer (score 1):

**C99 standard on `stdbool`**

The [C99 N1256 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.16 "Boolean type and values `<stdbool.h>`" says:

> 1 The header `<stdbool.h>` defines four macros.
>
> 2 The macro `bool` expands to `_Bool`.
>
> 3 The remaining three macros are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives. They are
>
> ```
> true
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant 1,
>
> ```
> false
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant 0, and
>
> ```
> _ _bool_true_false_are_defined
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant 1.
>
> 4 Notwithstanding the provisions of 7.1.3, a program may undefine and perhaps then redefine the macros bool, true, and false.222)

A key insight is that the names `bool`, `true` and `false` need a header because they are not reserved as they don't start with underscore. But `_Bool` is a reserved identifier, so they could just add it to C99 without requiring a new header.

Then 6.2.5 "Types" defines `_Bool`:

> 2 An object declared as type `_Bool` is large enough to store the values 0 and 1.

The fact that it was added in C99 is stated on the changeset summary section "Foreword"

> 5 This second edition cancels and replaces the first edition, ISO/IEC 9899:1990, as amended and corrected by ISO/IEC 9899/COR1:1994, ISO/IEC 9899/AMD1:1995, and ISO/IEC 9899/COR2:1996. Major changes from the previous edition include:
>
> [...]
>
> - boolean type in <stdbool.h>

Related:

- [Using Boolean values in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c)
- [Is bool a native C type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was just a feature that appeared in c99 And you can use it by adding the header file  #include <stdbool.h>

Answer (score -8):

Try this header file in your code

```
stdbool.h
```

This must work

Comment: This is just repeating the existing answers.

Comment: how does this provide more information than other 5-year-old answers?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu it does provide an answer  (even if you think it is low quality)

Comment: and I just noticed it there are two answers which are only repetition of pmg's answers.