# Why to use a const int and not a #define when declaring true and false

Tags: c, boolean

I am starting with C and OpenGL and came across the situation where I wanted to have true and false as boolean values, but couldn't get them, since they don't exist as such in C. I then came up with the idea to use the `#define` to just define them in a utils.h I use in almost all other files anyways, but wanted to check if that is okay with the standards or if there is some reason one shouln't do that. I then came across a [site](https://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Ejbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/Decisions.html), which made it clear, that this is ok for convenience, but had a little section which left me confused:

```
To make life easier, C Programmers typically define the terms "true" and "false" to 
have values 1 and 0 respectively.

In the old days, this was done using #define:
    #define true 1
    #define false 0
Today it is better to use const int instead of #define:
    const int true = 1;
    const int false = 0;
```

Is that true, and if so, why is that better?

Eventually I just went with `stdbool.h`, as described there, but the other thing really left me puzzled.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6118846/1216776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upside of making them `const int` is that they are proper variables and you can't make mistakes when defining and using them as easily which is often the case with `#define`s.

But, I wouldn't say it's better to make them `const int` since they then couldn't be used where compile-time constant expressions are needed. I would have suggested:

```
enum { false, true };
```

That would give you the same upside as making them `const int` (they are in fact `const int` but compile-time constants) - but they would also be usable in situations where you need a compile-time constant expression.