# VS Code's C/C++ extension says the C23 true and false keywords are undefined

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am using the C/C++ Extension from Microsoft in VS Code. I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    bool b;
    b = true;
    printf("b is %d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

VS Code marks `true` as being a problem and says `identifier "true" is undefined`.

I *believe* I've set up my `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file correctly to use the latest C standard (in which `true` and `false` are defined).

```
{
    "version": 4,
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c23"
        }
    ]
```

If I compile from the command line (using the same clang), it builds without warnings and the program runs as expected.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6/bin/clang main.c -o main -std=c2x | ./main
```

Any ideas as to where my issue lies? How can I get VS Code to accept `true` and `false`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which header file do you include to use bool type in c in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118846/which-header-file-do-you-include-to-use-bool-type-in-c-in-linux)

Comment: As for C23, c_cpp_properties.json does not set the C version for the compiler. It should be set in tasks.json.

Comment: [true and false are valid keywords in C23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)#Constants). So I shouldn't need to include a header. This is demonstrated by the fact that it compiles perfectly fine from the command line without including <stdbool.h>.

Comment: @273K they're saying they're getting a VS Code "problem" (that's a special word in VS Code for things that show up in the Problems Panel and get rendered with an underline in the editor area). they're not talking about a compiler diagnostic from executing a build task.

Comment: Consider using Clangd instead of the stock intellisense. If you use Clang as a compiler, it will never disagree with the compiler.

Comment: What setting do I set to use clangd?

Comment: @guy it's not a setting for the C/C++ extension. it's its own extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known current issue. See issue ticket [C23 features aren't supported #10696](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10696). You can give it a thumbs up to show support for it and increase its prioritization. At the time of this writing, the C/C++ extension is blocked waiting on the EDG parser (see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10696#issuecomment-1474184017) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10696#issuecomment-1706990059) comment).

One of the C/C++ extension maintainers gave a workaround [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/11718#discussioncomment-7635890):

> add `"true=1"` and `"false=0"` to the `"defines"` array in your `c_cpp_properties.json`

There may be some extra weirdness you may have to deal with. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10696#issuecomment-1969944610) for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks for answer and the workaround!