# Why is the return type of isalpha() int and not bool?

Tags: c++, c, function

Why is the return type of a C function like `isalpha()` `int` instead of being `bool` as it is used in C# etc?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. I agree that it is unrelated to the question about int/bool, but in any case perhaps a code example?

Comment: @pb2q Question has been updated ;)

Answer (score 11):

Using zero for *false* and non-zero for *true* is used extensively in C standard library functions. Many of these functions originated before any `bool` (or `BOOL`, `_Bool`) types were generally used.

Specifically, functions such as `isalpha` are specified in C89, but a boolean type not until C99.

So expect to see this all over the C standard library functions. You'll typically see `bool` used in C++ code.

Comment: Hm, saying it is "commonly used" is sort of an understatement. The standard *defines* `false` to be `0` and `true` to be `1`.

Comment: @LokiAstari C99 7.16 specifies _stdbool.h_ with `true`, `false`, `bool`, and that `true` expands to _1_, `false` to _0_; but none of these are specified earlier, e.g. ANSI C, which do have e.g. `isalpha`.

Answer (score 9):

There was no **bool** data type in the original **C**.

Check this answer for theory: [Is bool a native C type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type)

Answer (score 6):

Because C did not originally have a built-in bool type.

Comment: C99 does have a boolean type.

Comment: @Mat: The old C didn't. Many functions come from there.

Comment: Well, that comment is more informative and correct than your answer.

Answer (score 6):

C didn't have a dedicated Boolean data type before the 1999 standard; prior to that, the language simply assumed that a non-zero integral expression represented True and a zero-valued integral expression represented False.

Much of the standard library (including the `isalpha` function) predates the introduction of the `bool` datatype, so those functions return `int` for Boolean values.  Why didn't WG14 change the interface with C99?  There's a *lot* of legacy code out there that was written under C89 and earlier, and such an interface change would break that code, which WG14 (the committee responsible for maintaining the language standard) is understandably loath to do.  Heck, it took them more than 20 years to get rid of the `gets` library call.

As for the second question, the output `<<` operator in C++ treats `char *` differently from other pointer types, and assumes that it points to the beginning of a C-style string.  If you want `<<` to display the actual pointer value, you need to cast it to `void *` (or do something similarly silly):

```
char *str = "This is a test";
...
cout << "str = " << str << "; address = " << (void *) str << endl;
```