# Unknown type name "bool" when compiling kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack

I am trying to compile a simple "hello world" kernel module for 3.8.13 on a beaglebone (ARM):

hello.c:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

void init_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "My Kernel Module is enabled.\n");
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "My Kernel Module is disabled.\n");
}
```

Whatever I try, I always get

```
In file included from /home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:1:0:
./include/linux/init.h:159:1: error: unknown type name 'bool'
```

I have tried re-installing kernel-dev, kernel-headers, "make headers_install", but no luck, and am running of ideas.

This is the Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o
KDIR = /usr/src/kernel
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

and the full output of make:

```
root@beaglebone:~/src/moduletest# make
make -C /usr/src/kernel M=/home/root/src/moduletest modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernel'
  CC [M]  /home/root/src/moduletest/hello.o
In file included from /home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:1:0:
./include/linux/init.h:159:1: error: unknown type name 'bool'
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c: In function 'init_module':
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:7:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'printk' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:7:16: error: 'KERN_INFO' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:7:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:7:26: error: expected ')' before string constant
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:8:9: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c: In function 'cleanup_module':
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:13:16: error: 'KERN_INFO' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:13:26: error: expected ')' before string constant
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/root/src/moduletest/hello.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/root/src/moduletest] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernel'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Edit:**

It appears that gcc uses the user-space uapi/linux/types.h headers instead of linux/types.h. Adding gcc -v -H shows

```
GNU C (Linaro GCC 4.7-2013.02-01) version 4.7.3 20130205 (prerelease) (arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.7.3 20130205 (prerelease), GMP version 5.0.5, MPFR version 3.1.0, MPC version 0.8.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=64 --param ggc-min-heapsize=63851
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/src/kernel/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/src/kernel/arch/arm/include
 arch/arm/include/generated
 /usr/src/kernel/arch/arm/include/uapi
 arch/arm/include/generated/uapi
 /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi
 include/generated/uapi
 arch/arm/mach-omap2/include
 arch/arm/plat-omap/include
 ./include <-------- this refers to /usr/src/kernel/include and should be above the "uapi" line
End of search list.
```

and this include tree:

```
. ./include/linux/init.h
.. ./include/linux/compiler.h
... ./include/linux/compiler-gcc.h
.... ./include/linux/compiler-gcc4.h
.. /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/linux/types.h
... arch/arm/include/generated/asm/types.h
.... /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/asm-generic/types.h
..... /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/asm-generic/int-ll64.h
...... arch/arm/include/generated/asm/bitsperlong.h
....... /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h
... /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h
.... /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/linux/stddef.h
.... /usr/src/kernel/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/posix_types.h
..... /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h
...... arch/arm/include/generated/asm/bitsperlong.h
In file included from /home/root/src/moduletest/hello.c:8:0:
./include/linux/init.h:159:1: error: unknown type name 'bool'
. /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/linux/module.h
. /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/linux/kernel.h
.. /usr/src/kernel/include/uapi/linux/sysinfo.h
```

I have no idea why it does this. Adding -I /usr/src/kernel/include does not work as it is assumed to be a system directory and thus gets put to the end of the include path list.

Comment: Straight up C doesn't have a bool type I believe.  Use an int. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Objective-C.2C_Awk.2C_Perl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is bool a native C type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type) In particular, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608377/827263), which is relevant to the Linux kernel (which defines its own `bool` type rather than using the C99 standard `<stdbool.h>`). Just add `#include <linux/types.h>`

Comment: <linux/init.h> does include <linux/types.h>, which #defines bool for kernel modules. I narrowed it down, see the edit.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else banging their head, I got it to work by replacing the line

```
NOSTDINC_FLAGS += -nostdinc -isystem $(shell $(CC) -print-file-name=include)
```

in /usr/src/kernel/Makefile by

```
NOSTDINC_FLAGS += -nostdinc
```

and using the following Makefile for building the modules:

```
obj-m+=hello.o
KDIR=/usr/src/kernel
PWD:=$(shell pwd)
ccflags-y=-I /usr/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/include

all:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

This appears to fix the include path order and puts the kernel "/usr/src/kernel/include" before all the uapi paths.