# Program doesn't end after parsing "exit"

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am trying to learn, so go easy on me :D

I am currently trying to make a simple bank account console application. I got the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void parseCommand(char cmd[15], bool end) {
    if(cmd != NULL) {
        if(strstr(cmd, "listaccounts") != NULL) {

        } else if(strstr(cmd, "addaccount") != NULL) {

        } else if(strstr(cmd, "removeaccount") != NULL) {

        } else if(strstr(cmd, "withdraw") != NULL) {

        } else if(strstr(cmd, "deposit") != NULL) {

        } else if (strstr(cmd, "exit") != NULL) {
            end = true;
        } else {
            printf("Unknown Command: %s\n", cmd);
        }
    } else {
        printf("cmd is null");
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Welcome to the Account Management System\n");
    printf("Please use one of the following commands:\n");
    bool end = false;
    while(true) {
        printf("\tlistaccounts\n");
        printf("\taddaccount\n");
        printf("\tremoveaccount\n");
        printf("\twithdraw\n");
        printf("\tdeposit\n");
        printf("\texit\n");
        char cmd[15];
        fgets(cmd,15,stdin);
        parseCommand(cmd, end);
        if(end == true) {
            printf("Shutting down...");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I type "exit" the program just starts over in the while loop and asks for new input. What am I doing wrong? My guess would be how I try to compare two strings.

Comment: to start with, you forgot to include "stdbool.h"

Comment: You never actually set end. You pass it to a function, put this does not change its value unless it is a pointer. I would suggest changing the function from a void to a boolean here, then when you return, just check that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 'parseCommand' to change the variable from the main function, you should pass a pointer of it.

```
void parseCommand(char cmd[15], bool * end) {
if(cmd != NULL) {
    if(strstr(cmd, "listaccounts") != NULL) {

    } else if(strstr(cmd, "addaccount") != NULL) {

    } else if(strstr(cmd, "removeaccount") != NULL) {

    } else if(strstr(cmd, "withdraw") != NULL) {

    } else if(strstr(cmd, "deposit") != NULL) {

    } else if (strstr(cmd, "exit") != NULL) {
        *end = true;
    } else {
        printf("Unknown Command: %s\n", cmd);
    }
} else {
    printf("cmd is null");
}
}

int main() {
    printf("Welcome to the Account Management System\n");
    printf("Please use one of the following commands:\n");
    bool end = false;
    while(true) {
        printf("\tlistaccounts\n");
        printf("\taddaccount\n");
        printf("\tremoveaccount\n");
        printf("\twithdraw\n");
        printf("\tdeposit\n");
        printf("\texit\n");
        char cmd[15];
        fgets(cmd,15,stdin);
        parseCommand(cmd, &end);
        if(end == true) {
            printf("Shutting down...");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the first time I've had to use a pointer. But given all the other answers to this question, I see now why I have to. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

In C, the variables are passed by value. So whatever value `end` will have in your parseCommand method, the outer function will not see it. An easy way to fix it is to make your function to return `end`:

```
bool parseCommand(char cmd[15], bool end) {
///
  return end;
}


// in main:

end = parseCommand(cmd, end);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it does. Thanks, but I changed it so that I pass a pointer to the bool instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to modify the value of a variable declared outside the function. You need a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

To compile, first add `#include <stdbool.h>`.

---

In your code, you're passing `end` using pass-by-value. This will create a local copy of `end` inside `parseCommand()` scope. Whatever it done with `end` value inside `parseCommand()` code will not be reflected to `main()`.

1. change `parseCommand(cmd, end);` to `parseCommand(cmd, &end);`
2. change `void parseCommand(char cmd[15], bool end)` to `void parseCommand(char cmd[15], bool *end)`
3. change `end = true;` to `*end = true;`

Also, `if(cmd != NULL)` should be changed to `if ((cmd != NULL) && (end != NULL))`

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR sorry i did not get you.

Comment: Why do I need to import stdbool.h first when the code compiles fine?

Comment: @vipar `import` and `c` ?

Comment: You know what I mean. Why include stdbool.h when the code compiles?

Comment: @Vipar maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608350/2173917) will end the confusion.

Comment: it doesn't really explain why I need to include it when the program runs fine without it.

Comment: @Vipar well, it **does** explain. For me, it won't compile. with `gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)`, it throws error for undeclared `bool`, and as per the `c` tag, i'm suppossed to compile this gith `gcc`, not `g++`, right? [assuming you're on linux]

Answer (score 1):

When you pass say `void parseCommand(char cmd[15], bool end)`, you are creating duplicate variables local to the scope of the function (you may want to look up scope).  Thus `bool end` becomes a duplicate local to the function, and when the function finishes, it cannot be accessed again.  You could use a pointer and make `bool end` into `bool *end`, or you could have the function return a `bool`, by saying `bool parseCommand(char cmd[15], bool end)`

Comment: I know what scope is, but I forgot that C passes by value :)

Comment: I was going to up-vote you for a right answer, but don't ask for up-votes dude :P