# What is the proper equivalent of "while(true)" in plain C?

Tags: c, algorithm

Since C doesn't have `bool`s, what is the proper variable to put in place of `true` in an algorithm that uses

```
do
{
   // ... 
} while(true);
```

???

Should a proper C programmer do

```
do
{
   // ... 
} while(1);
```

or is there a specific variable reserved to mean "s*omething that is not zero/NULL*" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using boolean values in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c)

Comment: Modern C does have bools (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type/1608350#1608350).

Comment: `#include <stdbool.h>` -- Congratulations, you now have `bool`, `true` and `false` in 2015 (and 1999, for that matter)!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Usually nowadays I see

```
while(1) {
    ...
}
```

It used to be common to see

```
for(;;) {
    ...
}
```

It all gets the point across.

Comment: Some compilers issue a warning for loop condition expressions that are compile-time constant true; so for that reason prefer `for(;;)` in both C and C++.

Comment: `for(;;)` is more language independent (e.g. also works in Java) and is more intuitive in my opinion, I call it the `forever`.

Comment: `#define EVER ;;`,
`for(EVER) {}`

Answer (score 16):

Your question isn't really about `bool` (which modern C *does* have if you `#include <stdbool.h>`), it's about the best way to write an infinite loop.

Common idioms are:

```
while (1) {
    /* ... */
}
```

and

```
for (;;) {
    /* ... */
}
```

The latter looks a little obscure, but it's well-defined. Any of the three expressions in a `for` loop header can be omitted; if the second expression, which controls when the loop continues to execute, is omitted, it defaults to true.

`while (1)` is probably the most straightforward method -- but some some compilers might warn about a condition that's always true. `for (;;)` likely avoids that, since there is no (explicit) expression to warn about.

I personally wouldn't use a `do`/`while` loop, because the condition is at the bottom.

There are trickier ways to write an infinite loop (`while (1 + 1 == 2)` et al, but none of them are really worth the effort.

Either `while (1)` or `for (;;)` will be perfectly clear to anyone with a good understanding of C.

Answer (score 8):

C has `stbool.h` header file to use `bool` variables.

So this works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int main(void) {
    int i=1;
    while(true)
    {
        if(i==3){       
        break;
        }
        printf("%d\n",i);
        i++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1  
2
```

note:Modern **C99** has support for `bool` variables but **C89/90** does not have.

If you are using C89/90 then you can use `typedef` or `constants` as mentioned in one of the answers here or you can use `enums` as well like this

```
   typedef enum {false, true } bool;    
   bool b=true;
   int i=1;
   while(b)
   {
        if(i==3){       
        break;
        }
        printf("%d\n",i);
        i++;
    }
```

output

```
1  
2
```

You can check this [bool in C](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-94/)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using c89:

Create a boolean definition:

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

Or constants:

```
/* Boolean constants. */
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

This gives the int a meaning for you.

Or (as mentioned elsewhere here) if using c99:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

My experience of universities lately, is they require you to use c89.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdbool.h

Comment: Or, more simply, `typedef enum { false, true } bool;`. Or, even more simply, `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @user3956566 no need to perpetuate such antiquities

Comment: @user3956566: In C89/C90, you can use the first alternative I mentioned. You can even get `__STDC_VERSION__` to pick one of the other.