# Using 0 and 1 as false and true in C

Tags: c, loops

I am learning C from a book and the author is explaining using 1 for true and 0 for false with while loops. He explained with the following the sample code but I couldn't understand it.

**INPUT**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n = 3;

    while (n)
        printf("%2d is true\n", n--);
    printf("%2d is false\n", n);


    n = -3;
    while (n)
        printf("%2d is true\n", n++);
    printf("%2d is false\n", n);


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3 is true
2 is true
1 is true
0 is false
-3 is true
-2 is true
-1 is true
0 is false
```

Comment: What did you not understand? And the correct wording is: `0 is false, everything else is true`.

Comment: 0 is false, any other number is true.

Comment: That's not exact. 0 means false but everything but 0 means true in a if statement or a while loop.

Comment: True is 1, but not everything that is true is 1.

Comment: Guys I am new to C so sometimes I don't know the correct phrase.

Comment: Get a more recent book. C has `_Bool` (mapped to the C++ names `bool` with `stdbool.h`, etc.) since C99. So do not use magic values (although `_Bool` actually _is_ an integer type with the correct conversions).

Comment: Seconding @Olaf: you should seriously consider using the modern `_Bool` type and the `stdbool.h` header. See [*Is bool a native C type?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type/1608350#1608350).

Comment: @Olaf The book is recent (2013) but the author was explaining how things worked in earlier days.

Comment: @dhiman007 Please elaborate which part you do and do not understand. E.g : Increment operator `n++`, decrement operator `n--`, condition in the loop `while(n)` etc

Comment: In "earlier days" we had to go to the river to wash our clothes. You should not learn how it was done back then, but how to do it now. Tempora mutantur.

Comment: And note: "true" is not only `1`, but `!0`: any value other than `0`. Which is exactly what you are relying on.

Comment: @dhiman007 it works exactly the same nowadays, unless you use `_Bool` type

Answer (score 7):

May be if you add braces you can understand the code properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n = 3;

    while (n)
    {
      printf("%2d is true\n", n--);
    }
    printf("%2d is false\n", n);

    n = -3;
    while (n)
    {
      printf("%2d is true\n", n++);
    }
    printf("%2d is false\n", n);


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The code that you posted and the above code are same. If there are no braces the next statement after the `while` will be executed.

This:

```
printf("%2d is true\n", n--);
```

in the first while will continue to execute until `while(n)` is false. `while(n)` is equivalent to `while(n!=0)`. `while(something)` is false only when something is 0.

So, when `n=3` the condition in the first loop is true and then `n--`(`n=n-1`) makes `n` 2 and for 2 the condition is true and so on. When `n` is 0 the condition becomes false and exits the loop. The program then prints false and similarly the second `while` loop is executed.

Answer (score 5):

There are several places in C where any expression are used a Boolean values deciding the program's flow:

- Conditional statement `if`
- Loop constructs `for`, `while`, and `do`-`while`
- Conditional expression `?`-`:`

In all these places where a Boolean value is *consumed*, an implicit `!= 0` is added, so

```
while (n)
```

means

```
while (n != 0)
```

Hence, all values other than zero are considered `true`.

There are other places in the language where a Boolean value is *produced* by a logical expression, e.g. the logical NOT `!` operator. In this case, the values produced are confined to the `0`, `1` set. Specifically, a logical NOT of a zero is `1`.

Comment: Okay I got that true and false part of the loop but I can't understand the things inside the loop.

Comment: `printf("%2d is true\n", n--);` prints `n` followed by `is true\n` and then, when `n` was printed, decrements `n` value by 1. You can read more [here](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx7b.html) or Google.

Answer (score 3):

In fact C treats 0 as `FALSE` and non-0 as `TRUE`.

Comment: I got it that 0 for false and 1 for true but why it produces the following output?

Comment: `while` loops continue as long as the condition in them is *false*. The numbers 3, 2, and 1 are all "true" values, so we keep looping; as soon as the loop hits 0, it terminates.

Answer (score 2):

The first time it reaches `while(n)` the value of `n` is `3`. 
Because only `0` counts a false, `3` counts are true and that statement amounts to `while(3)` that is "while true" so the following line gets executed:

```
printf("%2d is true\n", n--);
```

That line outputs the value of `n`. 
If you don't understand why that is going to output that value go back a chapter or two and read up on `printf(.)`. I don't know what book you're reading but I assume it follows a logical order and introduced output pretty early on.

That line also subtracts one from n (that's what `n--` means).
If you don't understand that, again go back a bit.
That expression reduces `n` by one but returns its value before the subtraction.

That results in the first line of output:

```
3 is true
```

Then the program loops back to the while condition. Now `n` is `2`. But `2` still counts as true so the in-loop code (the first `printf`) gets executed again giving:

```
2 is true
```

And ends with `n` holding the value `1`. That leads to one further execution of the in-loop code giving

```
1 is true
```

Now that execution leaves with `n` having the value `0`. That counts as false so the loop condition `while(n)` is `while(0)` which means "while false".

So execution bypasses the in-loop code and executes:

```
printf("%2d is false\n", n);
```

The leads to the line

```
0 is false
```

The rest of the program does a similar thing in reverse starting with `n` having the value `-3` and then incrementing it (by `n++`) till again it hits false (`n` being `0`).

That gives the lines

```
-3 is true
-2 is true
-1 is true
0 is false
```