# Are there any risks or gotchas when using C bools as integers

Tags: c, boolean

I sometimes find that using bools in integer expressions make for shorter and simpler code.
For example I prefer

```
int n_items = has_a + has_b + has_box * 5;
```

over

```
int n_items = (has_a ? 1 : 0) + (has_b ? 1 : 0) + (has_box ? 5 : 0);
```

This should be safe since false==0 and true==1. Are the any risks or gotchas one should know about?

With bools I mean either C99 bools or boolean expressions like `a>b`. Of course I have to watch out for values that are not actually boolean, like the return value of `isdigit()`.

Comment: This is a great way to write very confusing code.

Comment: There is no such thing as a boolean. C only has integers, so this question makes no sense. "Booleans" are **already integers**. There is [`_Bool`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type) in C99, but again this still holds the *unsigned integer* value of `1` or `0`.

Comment: @meagar: There is a datatype `_Bool`/`bool` in C. However, it actually **is** an unsigned integer type with values `0` and `1`.

Comment: Boolean expressions do not yield a `bool` result, but an `int` (compatibility).

Comment: xxbbcc, Richard Chambers: What specifically do you find confusing or unsafe about this?

Comment: C has no boolean type, so the first approach is perfectly okay. But you have to be sure that it will never happen that f.e
`has_a = -1` and `has_b = 1`
In this case both will be true but adding them will be false

Comment: In theory this should be safe, but it depends how you're storying your booleans. As far as the `if` statement is concerned, zero is false, and non-zero is true (so not necessarily 1!). So booleans with true values aren't necessarily stored as `1`. I guess the `bool` type ensures `1` is stored for all `true` values though?

Comment: @Emi1303 C has `_Bool` boolean type.

Comment: It heavily depend on the functions that returns those values. You need to require all of them to return 1 for true.

Comment: I have worked with a C compiler, where 'true' was defined as 2 rather than 1.  Such experiences have me testing for 'false' and '!false'  I.E. I never check directly for the 'value' of 'true'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the risk with `bool` is it has a different semantic than `int` and a lot of programs already use `bool` as an alias to `int` and are not using C99 `_Bool` typedef from `stdbool.h` (e.g., programs developed for C89 or meant to be compatible with):

`typedef int bool;`

Then this expression for example may have different meanings:

```
int a = (bool) 0.5;  // if bool is _Bool, evaluates to 1
                     // if bool is int, evaluates to 0
```

This can create some really nasty bugs.

On other hand a shorter form than `(has_a ? 1 : 0)` is the idiomatic `!!has_a`.