# How to return opposite of true or false?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I was interview in company and I was asked a question, question was bit strange so wanted to ask with expert guys.

The question suppose I have function which returns bool type. Let us say this :

```
public bool func(int param)
{
  bool retVal;

 // here is some algorithm which as a result either set the retVal to false or true, 
 // It doesn't matter what is algo, the only thing important is it either do 
 // retVal=false or retVal=true

 // The question is i have to write the algo here which in case 
 // if the previous algo gives us retVal=false then it should 
 // return true and if retVal=true then return false      

}
```

**What should be that algo ?**

Comment: That function you show, that's not C. Please use the *correct* language tag.

Comment: A bit odd that a `C` interview (as you tagged it) would ask about `bool` (and not `_Bool`, see for example [Is bool a native C type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type)). See also @JoachimPileborg's comment above. Was it `C++` maybe? It's not the same thing, and some interviewers pay attention to such confusion.

Comment: TIL: `!` is an *algorithm*.

Comment: If you don't know this, applying for jobs is a waste of everybody's time. You need an introductory programming course.

Comment: @dxiv Nothing odd about it, `bool` is far more commonly used than `_Bool`. The use of `public` is mighty odd, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the result of the algorithm is in retval,

```
return (!retval);
```

Comment: Why the parenthesis? It adds nothing but clutter.

Comment: Adding a bracket adds clarity in many cases. The return bracket is just a matter of convention.

Comment: It rather suggests that the programmer isn't aware of how the return statement works nor how sequence points work.

Comment: As I said, it is a matter of convention. Please clarify your above statement.

Comment: What convention? You have absolutely no rationale for putting the parenthesis there, is my whole point. The C standard grammar is (6.8.6) `return expression_opt ;` where the expression is any plain C expression. So if you are consistent with your own "convention", you should write every single expression in your code inside a parenthesis. For example: `for((i=0); (i<n); (i++)) { if ((array[i] == x)) { (do_stuff()); } }`.

Comment: If you refer to MISRA C 2004 Section 10.2 in the example given it mentions `return (s32a);` Further below, in the same section it also mentions `return s16a;`. So that is why I say, it is a matter of convention. Both are perfectly accepted ways of writing C code. Writing code one way does not in any way give any other inferences on one's C ability.

Comment: If they randomly alternative between styles, that's even worse. It can only mean that the person who wrote the code is confused, period.

Comment: The MISRA document would have taken input from multiple people. So there are multiple conventions or styles in evidence. Again goes to show that both are accepted forms.

Comment: MISRA-C is a bad example since it is explicitly not a style guide. I was one of those multiple people giving input: the coding style used in the examples is not relevant to remark upon during review, since MISRA-C only requires that there exists a style guide, but makes no demands on what it should contain.

Comment: I agree that MISRA is not a style guide. However the C language does not have a definitive style guide. It just goes to show that there are multiple accepted forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code would be like this:

```
public bool func(int param)
{
   bool retVal;
   return !retVal;
}
```

Comment: I think not, this is not valid C.

Comment: Yeah, I have answered according to the asked question. I think it must be Java code.

Answer (score 0):

!retVal is the opposite of retVal. if retVal is true the !retval is false and vice-versa

```
public bool func(int param)
{
 bool retVal
 //your algo;
 return !retVal;

}
```