# error C2632: 'int' followed by 'bool' is illegal in VS 2015 (worked fine in VS 2013)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

My Solution consists of Multiple C++ and one C project using VS 2015.

I am getting error error C2632: 'int' followed by 'bool' is illegal on following line of code in C header file.

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef int bool;
#endif
```

this code was working fine in VS 2013

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Because C has a boolean type since ca. 17 years? Good to see MS also heard that finally. See `stdbool.h`

Comment: Thanks Olaf stdbool.h worked. I removed the above code and included stdbool.h

Comment: @Saifullah Zahid It is a wrong statement that C has a boolean type. C does not have a boolean type. C has integer type _Bool that has nothing common with type bool. The reason for the error can be either a bug of the compiler or there is already a typedef for name bool that uses a different type specifier. as for example typedef _Bool bool;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Was it not [added in C99](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608350/4892076) as part of the C standard library header <stdbool.h>? While it's not a keyword, it is reserved. From 7.26.7: "The ability to undefine and perhaps then redefine the macros `bool`, `true`, and `false` is an obsolescent feature."

Comment: @jaggedSpire First of all you have at first to include the header <stdbool.h>. I am sure that the author of the question does not use it. And secondly "obsolescent feature" means in fact nothing.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Concerning "C does not have a boolean type."  --> The C11 spec has "7.18 **Boolean type** and values <stdbool.h>" ... The macro `bool` expands to `_Bool` ...  Is the C committee wrong in calling that a boolean type?

Comment: @chux I am sure that the committee is wrong or uses this term in a very broad meaning. And there is no such type specifier as bool. Moreover in my first comment that you should reread one more I already wrote that bool can be a typedef for example for _Bool or other type. So your comment does not make any sense.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Sounds like we agree there is a type `_Bool` in C.   And I am sure you agree  `_Bool` can have 1 of 2 values (C11 6.2.5).  To me, that sounds like a [boolean type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type).  So the comment "C does not have a boolean type." appears inconsistent, hence the comment.

Comment: @chux There is a contradiction in the C Standard. Type _Bool belongs to unsigned integer types that stores two integer constant 1 and 0. Moreover I even do not know what built-in logical operator returns this "boolean" type.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: FYI: In C, logical and comparison operators yield an `int` result (very likely for legacy reasons). See [6.5.13p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13p3) and the other operators.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type