# Why isn't there any condition checking in the following for loop?

Tags: c

```
for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); i++) { ... }
```

The above `for` loop is the part of the program for converting a string to an integer in K&R on page 61.

There's no condition check in that `for` loop. How does it work?

Comment: Isn't `isspace(s[i])` the condition?

Comment: @DoctorMick dont know ,how the loop works ?

Comment: It increments `i` until `s[i]` is no longer a whitespace character.

Comment: @DoctorMick Okay But where is the checking condition ?. That is function which will return a value am i correct ?

Comment: Which is kind of a dangerous thing without checking the string length or array bound.

Comment: @tofro sorry I didnt get you

Comment: Note, in C, zero is considered `false`, and everything else is considered `true`

Comment: @Gireesh Kumar The loop does not check whether it is still inside string or array and will probably runout of bounds.

Comment: @tofro No, the code assumes it's working on a string, which is terminated with a 0 byte, and isspace() will return 0 at that point

Answer (score 2):

The loop terminates whenever the condition expression evaluates to 0. If for instance you see an expression like `i < 3`, you can think of it as `(i < 3) != 0`. So in this case, it's `isspace(s[i]) != 0` meaning it terminates at the first character that is not a space.

Comment: Surely it terminates when the condition evaluates to false, not 0?

Comment: @DoctorMick Sort of semantics there. C didn't even used to have a boolean type. Back then _true_ was any value that could decay to an integer value that was not equal to 0. Since `false == 0`, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @KurtStutsman Sorry I didnt get your answer . may i get a simple example ? `for (i=3; 7; i--)
    printf("hello world \n");
    getch();
    return 0;`

Comment: @DoctorMick: This is C. C does not have `false`. C conditions evaluate to integer `0` or `1`. C99 introduced `false` as a macro defined in `<stdbool.h>` and that macro still stands for `0`.

Comment: @AnT Yes and no. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608350/459615). _stdbool.h_ does define `false`.

Comment: To expand on @AnT C: conditions (e.g. `i > 9`) evaluate to `0` or `1` but _decisions_ (in `if`, `while` etc.) are based on whether the expression evaluates to `0` or "not `0`".

Comment: `for (i=3; 7; i--) ` this loop will never terminate, since 7 is always not zero.

Comment: @Kurt Stutsman: Um... The answer you linked to is *my* answer. And it states exactly what I said here.

Comment: @AnT lol didn't see it was your answer. But you said there is no `false` in C on here, and that's not true by your own answer. You could say there is no `false` keyword I suppose. By that measure you could say `NULL` is not part of C either.

Comment: @Kurt Stutsman: What I meant is that the *core language* does not include dedicated boolean-specific constants. Even tough core language included a dedicated boolean type `_Bool`, this type still relies on `0` and `1` constants to represent "false" and "true" values. Everything else are library-level macro definitions.

Answer (score 1):

`isspace(s[i])` is the condition, since it returns a zero value for 'false' (i.e. the provided character is not a space character), and non-zero values for 'true'. In this case, only one space character exists, but in other functions such as `isalpha` or `isalphanum`, non-zero values mean different things like 1 means it is an upper-case letter (so it is an alphabetical character), or 2 means it is a lower-case letter) and so on (I may have mixed those numbers up :/).

In otherwords, the `for` loop is treating this function as returning a boolean value, like most other expressions, meaning it treats zero-values as `false`, and non-zero as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're going to get out of bounds, which is gonna give you a segfault. You're just increasing `i`, but not checking whether it's still in the bounds or not. For example, what if `s` would be equal to `" "`? `isspace(i[0])` will return a non-zero value (treated as true) and the loop will continue and will try to access the second (*non-existent!*) value of `s`. You'd better add another tiny check: `for (i = 0; (i<SIZE_OF_S) && isspace(s[i]); i++) { ... }`

Let's now talk about the missing condition. No, it's not missing, it's here: `isspace(s[i])`. This function checks whether `s[i]` is considered space or not. It returns a non-zero value if yes, and `0` otherwise ([docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/)). So, *it is the missing condition*, just in a slightly different form (maybe you're used to different comparisons, but there exist a lot more ways.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `isspace()` returns a non-zero value if the condiion is true. It's not necessarily equal to `1`.

Comment: @KurtStutsman, yeah, that's why the docs are there: to correct me if I'm a bit wrong. Will edit this in a minute

Comment: @ForceBru May i get another example ?

Comment: @GireeshKumar, another example of _what_?

Comment: @ForceBru thanks no need again example , I understood .. and i explained what i understood

Answer (score 0):

Yes If the for loop have  without condition checking  , **the for loop will exit whenever the condition  part will be zero**

For example

` 
    int i ;

```
for (i=0; 7-i; i++)
printf("hello world \n");
getch();
return 0;
```

}`

See the above program the 'i' minus the seven each time . and the loop will exit whenever the value of condition part will be zero (ie 7-7) .[image]