# Return value of a boolean expression in C

Tags: c, boolean, c99, c89

For reasons that are not worth mentioning, I want to know if there's a standard defined value for boolean expressions. E.g.

```
int foo () {
    return (bar > 5);
}
```

The context is that I'm concerned that our team defined TRUE as something different than 1, and I'm concerned that someone may do:

```
if (foo() == TRUE) { /* do stuff */ }
```

I know that the best option would be to simply do

```
if (foo())
```

but you never know.

Is there a defined standard value for boolean expressions or is it up to the compiler? If there is, is the standard value something included in C99? what about C89?

Comment: there is a standard type `bool` with constants `true` and `false` defined in the standard header `stdbool.h` since C99.

Comment: To complete what Eugene said, you might be interested by this link : http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually looking for argumentative facts to 1)change that definition of TRUE, and 2) use a C99 compliant compiler (right now, we're using a C89 compliant one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An operator such as `==`, `!=`, `&&`, and `||` that results in a boolean value will evaluate to 1 of the expression is true and 0 if the expression is false.  The type of this expressing is `int`.

So if the `TRUE` macro is not defined as `1`, a comparison such as the above will fail.

When an expression is evaluated in a boolean context, 0 evaluates to false and non-zero evaluates to true.  So to be safe, `TRUE` should be defined as:

```
#define TRUE (!0)
```

As was mentioned in the comments, if your compiler is C99 compliant, you can `#include <stdbool.h>` and use `true` and `false`.

According to [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

6.5.3.3 (Unary arithmetic operators)

> The  result  of  the  logical  negation  operator `!` is  0  if  the 
>   value  of  its  operand  compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its
>   operand compares equal to 0.  The result has type `int`.  The
>   expression  `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

6.5.8 (Relational operators)

> Each  of  the  operators `<` (less  than), `>` (greater  than), `<=`
>   (less  than  or  equal  to),  and `>=` (greater than or equal to)
>   shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. 
>   The result has type `int`.

6.5.9 (Equality operators)

> The `==` (equal  to)  and `!=` (not  equal  to)  operators  are 
>   analogous  to  the  relational operators  except  for  their  lower 
>   precedence. Each  of  the  operators  yields  1  if  the specified 
>   relation  is  true  and  0  if  it  is  false.   The result  has  type
>   `int`.

6.5.13 (Logical AND operator)

> The `&&` operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type `int`.

6.5.14 (Logical OR operator)

> The `||` operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0.  The result has type `int`.

Comment: Thanks. I expected that much. But I'm not sure if it evaluates to 1 by standard, or if that's something compiler-specific

Comment: @JACH Added addtional notes from C99 regarding boolean expressions.

Comment: Detail: the _type_ of the result is `int` with `==, !=, &&, ||, !, >, >=, <, <=`

Comment: Thanks for the information. So it is defined in C99. It seems that C89 information is hard to come by and or does not exist. I guess another reason to switch to C99.

Comment: I think you could change the wording of *"So to be safe, TRUE should be defined as: `#define TRUE (!0)`"* to something akin to *"If you cannot remember what the value of true is in C (it is 1), you can use `#define TRUE (!0)`"* because I've seen high-rep people suggesting that `!0` is not always 1.

Answer (score 0):

The `C` programming language does not define **Boolean** value. Traditionally, the `C` programming language uses `integer` types to represent boolean data types.

**Boolean values in C:**

```
0 = false` 

Any other value = true`
```

Usually people will use `1` for true.

**C99** introduced the`_Bool` data type that is not available in other `C` derivates.See wikipedia link [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). Additionally, a new header `stdbool.h` has been added for compatibility reasons. This header allows programmers to use `boolean` types in the same way, as in `C++` language.

To use `bool` in `C`, we can use `enum` as below.

```
enum bool {
    false, true
};

bool value;
value = bool(0); // False
value = bool(1); // True

if(value == false)
    printf("Value is false");
else
    printf("Value is true");
```

Also, related Stack overflow question
[Is bool a native C type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type)

Comment: Thanks for the link, very informative. My question, though, was more related to the result of boolean operations, since we internally are using already TRUE or FALSE as a pseudo-boolean type.

Comment: This exactly does not answer the question. And the use of an `enum` in C for a boolean type is a very bad idea!