# GetFileAttributes fails with absolute paths

Tags: c++, winapi

I was making a simple program with WinAPI to check if a directory exists, this is the function code:

```
BOOL directoryExists( LPCSTR path ) {
    DWORD pathAttributes = GetFileAttributes ( path );

    return pathAttributes != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES 
                  && pathAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
 }
```

Then I test it with this line of code in my main:

```
 std::cout << ( ( directoryExists( "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop" ) ?  
                          "Directory found"  : "Directory not found"  ) 
          << static_cast< char >( 0xA );
```

It looks like I get "Directory not found" no matter what absolute path I try to input. Anyway with relative paths it succeeds!

Where did I fail? :|

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value of `GetFileAttributes` is a bit field, not a single value, and each file attribute constant contains a bit mask so you should check it like this:

```c++
return (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES != pathAttributes) 
              && (0 != (pathAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
```

Also you should use `GetFileAttributesW` and wide char paths because `GetFileAttributesA` can not handle Unicode paths.

Comment: Thanks man, you're absolutely right! I edited as you suggested and everything works now :) I'll accept your answer as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking [FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) bit properly.
Try this:

```
BOOL directoryExists(LPCSTR path)
{
    DWORD attr = GetFileAttributes(path);
    return attr != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && (attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << (directoryExists("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\") ?
        "Directory found" : "Directory not found") << endl;
}
```

Comment: `BOOL` return value in a C++ program?

Comment: @zett42 yes, what's the problem? It's Windows.h

Comment: Because C++ has a build-in data type for that.

Comment: @zett42 WinAPI commonly uses BOOL for return types. I'd definitely use `bool` myself, but original code from the author had `BOOL`, I didn't invent that.

Comment: That's a fair point!

Comment: @zett42 Is that a so bad practice? I don't have much experience cause I'm just a student, but as far as I've seen many windows.h functions have WINBOOL return type!

Comment: @Baffo That's because windows.h is a C API that was invented when [C didn't have a native `bool` type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608350/7571258). It's better to use native `bool` type for your own functions because you can't overload on `BOOL` (it will create ambiguity when there is already an `int` overload) for instance. Also template specializations like `std::vector<bool>` can be completely different than `std::vector<BOOL>` (which actually is `std::vector<int>`).

Comment: @zett42 Nice to know that! I'll swap to bool :)