# How to recongnise C or C++

Tags: c++, c

I have some code, and I can't work out if it is written in C or C++.

According to [this article](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html):

I believe that it is C, as there are functions which are declared after use eg.

```
void main() {
    foo();
}

void foo() {
    printf( "Hello world" );
}
```

However, it does have a native boolean type - according to the website above:

> C does not provide a native boolean type. You can simulate it using an
>   enum, though: typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} bool;

Any idea if the code would be C, C++ or something else? Or any common things to look out for?

In addition, when I declare a variable outside a function then I have to write:

```
int test;
```

And then assign it a value in a function, instead of being able to do:

```
int test = 5;
```

Comment: If you're writing C++, then you're making use of it's object-oriented and template features and that's nothing like what you would see in C.

Comment: declaration after use is bad in c and c++, the difference being that c will compile it with a warning, c++ will fatal it

Comment: it's probably C, since `foo` has a default prototype (still bad practice)

Comment: what does "However, it does have a native boolean type." mean?

Comment: @pm100 see updated question

Comment: Doesnt make it any clearer, your code makes not mention of 'bool' or anything like it

Comment: An enum named "bool" would not compile in C++, since it's a reserved keyword.  If you see any C++ keywords used as variable names, it's definitely C and cannot be valid C++.  (Excluding the contextual keywords in c++ like "override" which only has meaning when declaring a function, and elsewhere is still allowed to be an ordinary identifier name.)

Comment: Actually, C99 does have [a native boolean type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type).

Comment: If this was C99 or later it would use `_Bool`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It uses *implicit function declarations* (for `foo()` and `printf()`, so if it is anything, it is C89. Implicit function declarations were never in C++, and were removed from C in C99.

---

To answer the question "how to recognise C or C++", there is a great deal of C++ that isn't valid C, and there is a smaller amount of C that isn't valid C++. So a reasonable level of knowledge of both languages is needed.

Comment: How did you know this!? Also this is likely way more specific than the OP was looking for. But still, +1.

Comment: You could also mention `void main` which is never c++.

Comment: @Fantastic Mr Fox - some people actually *read* the standards, and some of us have been doing so for *decades*.

Comment: @Fantastic It's not valid in C either, at least for hosted implementations - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I *think* the same rules apply re. the `void` return type, i.e. it is allowed in a "freestanding" implementation. But I have to check the C89 standard for that.

Answer (score 4):

The code you've shown is definitely not C++ (C++ doesn't allow implicit declarations), although it's not strictly correct C, either. The implicit `int` declaration of `foo` (which would only be valid in C89) is contradicted by the explicit `void` declaration/definition later - any decent C compiler should yell at you about this.

Also, `void` isn't a proper return type for `main` in either C or C++ (at least in a hosted implementation).

One really easy way to tell if code is C++ is to look at the standard headers.  If the headers don't have a trailing `.h`, like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

etc., then you're definitely looking at C++ code.  If the code uses the memory allocation operators `new` and `delete`, then you're definitely looking at C++ code.  If you see the scope resolution operator `::` anywhere, you're definitely looking at C++ code.  There are a few other C++-specific features (templates, lambdas, etc.) that are not found in C.

C++ doesn't allow variable-length arrays, while C99 and later do - if you see an array declaration where the size is given by a runtime variable, like

```
int size = 20;
int arr[size];
```

then you're definitely looking at C99 or later.

Unfortunately, that's where it stops being so easy.  C++ can use `stdio.h` routines, as well as `malloc` and `free` for memory management.  It's possible to write code that compiles as both C *and* C++, mainly by avoiding C++-specific syntax and keywords and by sticking with the C standard library.