# "Double free or corruption" error inside this function?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

Below is my function. It runs correctly once, then when it is called a second time it causes an error telling me "double free or corruption". I tried adding the +1 inside the malloc() as other posts have suggested, even though I am not storing null-terminated strings but arrays of integers. It did not help.

I am very confused at this point. I don't understand why at the end of the function the pointer that was free()'d doesn't go out of scope, or if it does, then how it can be considered a double-free when I malloc()'d after free()ing it the last time it was used.

```
int getCount(int number) {

    int totalUniqueDigits = 0;

    bool* allDigits = (bool*)malloc(10 * sizeof(bool));

    do {
        int currentDigit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        allDigits[currentDigit] = true;
    } while (number > 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {   
        if (allDigits[i] == true) {     
            totalUniqueDigits++;        
        }
    }

    free(allDigits);    /*This is where the problem is, but only the second time the function is called. */ 
    allDigits = NULL;

    return totalUniqueDigits; 
}
```

Comment: I can also share the function that is calling this one if needed, but it is much longer and I'm not sure of its relevance.

Comment: This is all there is in the function? what was the input `number`? Also you are comparing uninitialized value - which is UB. You are doing `i+=2` - why so?

Comment: If `number` is negative, then `currentDigit` will be negative also, and you'll write out of bounds. On most systems, writing to `allDigits[-1]` would overwrite information used to manage memory.

Comment: HA YES IT IS THE NEGATIVE VALUE I MUST ADD AN ABSOLUTE VALUE FUNCTION IN THERE! YES!

Comment: @CrisLuengo.: If number is negativem result will be negative also...`-10%10=0` not always. But in case neg its problem as you mentioned.

Comment: It was exactly that. In the sample data instuctor provided, the second value was negative. I feel stupid, but thanks very much Cris Luengo :)

Comment: Please add an answer to this interesting question (doing it yourself is fine). It gets it out of the list of unanswered questions. (Or maybe you, @CrisLuengo.)

Comment: Patrick, please change language from C to C++. C doesn't have built-in boolean types. It won't compile in gcc standalone.

Comment: I have included #include "stdbool.h" in another part of the program, does this change things BedBad?

Comment: @bedbad: `<stdbool.h>` defines macros `bool`, `true` and `false`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608321/5059838
No it's not. Please check the standard. If you want to change tag to c99 or c11 you ask that too, but its different languages from C.

Comment: @bedbad C99 **is** C. "C" doesn't mean K&R C, you're not complaining about the function signature either. C evolves, just like any other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `number` is negative, then

```
currentDigit = number % 10;
```

will be negative also (or zero if divisible by 10). This is a somewhat awkward (IMO) definition of the modulus operator.

If `currentDigit` is negative, then

```
allDigits[currentDigit] = true;
```

will write out of bounds. On most systems, writing to `allDigits[-1]` would overwrite information used to manage memory. This might not directly crash your program, but using `malloc` later could have that effect.

The solution of course is to either use `abs` or add `10` to `currentDigit` if it is negative.

Answer (score 0):

The array index was not being checked for negative values. Case Closed. Thanks Cris.

Comment: first post, gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

The Code you have posted runs with no error for all positive integers. It is C++ code, not C code.
If it's a C code you need to show declaration of "bool", "true" and "false",
otherwise there is no mistake inside of the provided function, execution wise.

Here's a full C++ program to test it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int getTotalUniqueEvenDigitCount(int number) {

    int totalUniqueDigits = 0;

    bool* allDigits = (bool*)malloc(10 * sizeof(bool));

    do {
        int currentDigit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        allDigits[currentDigit] = true;
    } while (number > 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {   
        if (allDigits[i] == true) {     
            totalUniqueDigits++;        
        }
    }

    free(allDigits);    /*This is where the problem is, but only the second time the function is called. */ 
    allDigits = NULL;

    return totalUniqueDigits; 
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  cout << getTotalUniqueEvenDigitCount(stoi(argv[1]));
  return 0;
}
```

Test it as

```
$<progname> number
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I just didn't know negative integers is in a domain. Calling [] with a negative number is obviously an error.